# Exception Type: AttributeError Exception Value: object has no attribute. What is wrong?

Tags: python, database, django

I have a table in my database, region

```
class region(models.Model):
    region_name = models.CharField(primary_key=True,max_length=50, null=False)

    @classmethod
    def __unicode__(self):
        return "hello"
```

When I am trying to add several new instances of region into the DB through the admin interface, so the title of all the existing regions is "hello", so I update the `__unicode__(self)` function as

```
@classmethod
def __unicode__(self):
    return u'%s' %(self.region_name)
```

but now the admin displays

```
Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value:    
type object 'region' has no attribute 'region_name'
```

I have check my DB and there is region_name in the table for region. Can anyone help why this happens?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't be using a `@classmethod`. Just remove the `@classmethod` decorator for the `__unicode__` function; the first parameter to a function decorated with `@classmethod` is the class itself, and not the model instance for your `region` instance.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12179752/1211429) provides a good overview of the purpose and use of `classmethod` and `staticmethod` function decorators in Python.