# How to define a method like int.from_bytes() in Python?

Tags: python, class, methods, python-3.x

In python there is a method on the type `int`, namely `int.from_bytes`. It's not a method on a particular int, instead it's a method on the type. E.g.

```
>>> int.from_bytes(b'\xee\xff',"big")
61183

>>> int.from_bytes
<built-in method from_bytes of type object at 0x107fdb388>
```

How do I define something like this? Let's say a class called "point" is defined, how do I define something like

```
>>> point.from_coordinates(3,5)
<__main__.point object at 0x10c0c9310>

>>> point.from_keys(b'\x12\x3e')
<__main__.point object at 0x10bed5890>
```

? (Assuming points are initialized by some different method.)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python @classmethod and @staticmethod for beginner?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12179271/python-classmethod-and-staticmethod-for-beginner)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want [`classmethod`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#classmethod), which is normally used as a decorator:

```
class point(object):
    @classmethod
    def from_coordinates(cls, x, y):
        pt = cls()
        pt.x, pt.y = x, y
        return pt
```

---

This is sometimes called the "alternate constructor" idiom. If there are multiple different ways to construct your type, instead of putting them all into one `__init__` method with a mess of optional parameters or varags, put them all into separate `classmethod`s.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a `classmethod`, such as the mocked up example whose `init` expects ints, but also provides a convenient `from_hex` that tries to take strings and convert them to integers...

```
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
    @classmethod
    def from_hex(cls, a, b):
        return cls(int(a, 16), int(b, 16))
```

The `from_hex` knows which class it is associated with, so by calling `cls(...)` you're able to construct a type of `MyClass` as though you'd written `MyClass(a, b)` with valid integers yourself.