# Python - Access class member without initialization of object

Tags: python

In the Python module "Wave" I can use the following syntax:

```
import wave
wave.open("test.wav", "rb")
```

This works perfectly fine.Let's say I wanted to use my own initialization of a class:

```
class Wave():

   def __init__(self):
       pass; 

   def Open(self, fileName, Type):
       return True; # Just testing
```

Now If I have "main" which calls this class, why can't I do the following?:

```
if Wave.Open("testing.wav", "rb"): 
   print "The file is open"
```

> TypeError: unbound method Open() must be called with Wave instance as first argument (got str instance instead)

Comment: `Wave().Open("testing.wav", "rb")` call it through an instance or convert `Open` to a classmethod.

Comment: It's a `classmethod` not `staticmethod` there is a very good explanation [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12179752/1982962)

Answer (score 4):

To be able to call it like this you need to make `Open` a static method:

```
@staticmethod
def Open(fileName, Type):
   ...
```

The difference between your code and the example you give at the start is that `wave` is a module, and `Wave` is a class. You could turn `Wave` into a module and have `Open` be a top-level function within that module.

Comment: @NPE Thanks I'm learning Python and did not know such things existed. :)

Comment: @alko: Actually, on second thoughts you could use either. I've removed my earlier comment.

Answer (score 3):

As the error states, you need an instance of the `Wave` class to call the `Open` method. Something like this should work:

```
if Wave().Open("testing.wav", "rb"): 
   print "The file is open"
```

Note the parenthesis after `Wave` - that's what creates the new instance.

If you want to be able to call this method without having an instance of the `Wave` class you could add a `@staticmethod` decorator to the `Open` function. This will allow you to call the method as you do in the code you provided.

Answer (score 3):

Other option, if you want your open method be class-specific, is `@classmethod` decorator, i.e.

```
class Wave():
   def __init__(self):
       pass;
   @classmethod 
   def open(cls, filename):
       print '{}.open method with args "{}"'.format(cls, filename)
       return True; # Just testing 

class SubWave(Wave): pass
```

and use as follows:

```
>>> Wave.open('filename')
__main__.Wave.open method with args "filename"
True

>>> SubWave.open('filename')
__main__.SubWave.open method with args "filename"
True
```