# Creating a Python classmethod

Tags: python, class, class-method

I've familiarized myself with the concept, most notably by watching Raymond Hettinger's excellent [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HTLu2DFOdTg) and reading the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12179271/python-classmethod-and-staticmethod-for-beginner) and I am wondering what I got wrong.

```
class ReadHTML(object):

    def __init__(self, url):
        page = urlopen(url).read()
        self.page = page

    @classmethod
    def from_file(cls, path):
        page = open(path).read()
        return cls(page)
```

This works

```
r = ReadHTML('http://example.com')
print r.page
```

and this is not

```
r = ReadHTML.from_file('example.html')
print r.page
```

it throws me an error, as if I was trying to "urlopen" a file:

```
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 258, in get_type
    raise ValueError, "unknown url type: %s" % self.__original
ValueError: unknown url type: <!doctype html>
```

Can you see what's wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are still calling the class initializer, `ReadHTML.__init__()`, when you call `cls(page)`; that call is no different from calling `ReadHTML(page)`, you are just using a different reference. This method only accepts a `url` parameter and the code passes that to `urlopen()` regardless.

Adjust your `ReadHTML.__init__()` method to handle being passed a page instead of a URL:

```
class ReadHTML(object):
    def __init__(self, url=None, page=None):
        if url is not None:
            page = urlopen(url).read()
        self.page = page

    @classmethod
    def from_file(cls, path):
        page = open(path).read()
        return cls(page=page)
```

Now the code supports both paths to produce an instance.

Comment: Great, thank you! I use Sublime Text2 (as you do I guess) and when I run `r = ReadHTML.from_file('example.html')
print r.page` Sublime's Build console shows me `[Finished in 1.0s]
[Finished in 0.7s]` at the bottom of the output. Still the output is correct but do you know where this double finish time come from? I never go it before. Can you check it out?

Comment: @nutship: I have no idea; I do use ST, but generally not the build system.

Comment: I know this is quite commonly done, but I believe parameters should not override each other like that.

Comment: @tawmas: The goal was to explain to the OP why their code failed. I'd also work out a better API here, and not necessarily override behaviour like this. It also depends on the typical use-case vs. the convenience class method, etc.

Answer (score 2):

`from_file` opens the page, but so does your `__init__()` constructor, so if you do `ReadHTML.from_file('example.html')`, you are essentially doing:

```
page = urlopen(open('example.html').read()).read()
```

Personally, I prefer [Martijn's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22046916/1142167), for semantic clarity, but here is an alternative:

```
class ReadHTML(object):
    def __init__(self, url, opener=urlopen):
        self.page = opener(url).read()

    @classmethod
    def from_file(cls, path):
        return cls(path, opener=open)
```

This solution is advantageous because it gives you the capability of defining arbitrary openers (say, for opening files stored in a database).

Comment: I like the extra flexibility of being able to override the opener, especially because this is needed to do anything fancy with urllib/urllib2.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a big fan of optional parameters overriding each other. I would make it so that the default constructor accepts a string and I would have to separate alternate constructors to handle a filename and an URL.

I also modified the filename constructor to explicitly close the file.

```
class ReadHTML(object):

    def __init__(self, page):
        self.page = page

    @classmethod
    def from_filename(cls, path):
        with open(path) as f:
            page = f.read()
        return cls(page)

    @classmethod
    def from_url(cls, url):
        page = urlopen(url).read()
        return cls(page)
```

As a side note, I believe urllib/urllib2 support file://, so you would strictly not need the filename constructor (but I still believe it is nice to have).