# How to change all objects of a class at once?

Tags: python, oop

I am rediscovering OOP through a GUI application I am writing and would like to understand if it is possible to change a characteristic of all objects instantiated from a class. I have the following code:

```
class myclass():
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 1

x = myclass()
y = myclass()
print x.a, y.a  # outputs 1 1
# the instruction I am looking for, assigns 2 to a in each object at once
print x.a, y.a  # outputs 2 2
```

What I am looking for is a way to change `x` and `y` at once by manipulating the parent class. **I know that I can have a method which modifies `self.a`** - I do not want to use that because it means I have to call it separately for each object.

My gut feeling is that this is not possible and that I have to cleverly handle my objects to simplify such activities (for instance by storing them in a list I would loop over, applying a method). I just do not want to miss a mechanism which I am not aware of and which would greatly simplify my code.

Comment: Wouldn't that be a situation where you'd use class variables instead of instance variables?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Static class variables in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/68645/static-class-variables-in-python)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can have all instances share a variable if you define it as a class variable:

```
>>> class myclass():
...     a = 1
...     def __init__(self):
...         self.b = 2
...
>>> x = myclass()
>>> y = myclass()
>>> x.a
1
>>> myclass.a = 2   # modify the class variable
>>> x.a
2
>>> y.a
2
>>> x.b = 3         # modify the instance variable
>>> x.b
3
>>> y.b
2
>>> x.a = 4         # create new local instance variable a
>>> x.a
4
>>> y.a
2
```

Note that now if you change `myclass.a`, you won't see the change in `x` because the instance variable will be looked up before the class variable - until you remove the instance variable using `del`:

```
>>> myclass.a = 3
>>> x.a
4
>>> y.a
3
>>> del x.a
>>> x.a
3
```

Answer (score 3):

No, you can't. Object data can't be changed without pointer to the object. Possibly you need class variables and [classmethod](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12179271/python-classmethod-and-staticmethod-for-beginner):

```
class myclass:
  a = 1
  @classmethod
  def set_a(cls, val):
    cls.a = val

x = myclass()
y = myclass()
print x.a, y.a  # outputs 1 1
myclass.set_a(2)
print x.a, y.a  # outputs 2 2
```

But in such case you cant change `a` value of objects separately. If you want such behavior you can save all instances of objects in classdata such follows:

```
class myclass:

  objects = []

  def __init__(self):
    self.a = 1
    # add instantiated object to object list 
    self.__class__.objects.append(self)

  @classmethod
  def set_all(cls, val):
    # go through list and change each object
    for obj in cls.objects:
      obj.a = 2

x = myclass()
y = myclass()
print x.a, y.a  # outputs 1 1
myclass.set_all(2)
print x.a, y.a  # outputs 2 2
# and you cat change data of each object separately:
x.a = 3
print x.a, y.a  # outputs 3 2
```

Comment: You may want to learn about `classmethod` stackoverflow.com/questions/12179271/python-classmethod-and-staticmethod-for-beginner

Comment: I know about `classmethod`. Would using `classmethod` change this answer dramatically?

Comment: Using a `staticmethod` and hardcoding the class name is bad practice. Since a lot of Python newbies might read your snippet, it would be better for them (and everyone that will have to maintain their code) to point them to the correct solution.

Comment: Agree. Updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
class myclass():
    a=10
    def __init__(self):
        self.b=0

a=myclass()
b=myclass()
print a.a,b.a #output 10,10
myclass.a=2
a=myclass()
b=myclass()


print a.a,b.a #output 2,2
```