# python oop get argument from user's input

Tags: python, oop

How can i make so, that user uses input() method for giving a value for argument wheels, to the class Car?:

```
class Car(object):
    def __init__(self, name, wheels):
        self.name = name
        self.wheels = wheels
first_car = Car()
```

Comment: to give a value for argument "wheels" for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

get the input from the user, pass it to the car

```
class Car(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
    ... etc etc

user_name = input("What name do you want?")
first_car = Car(user_name)
```

edit: You can also call the `input()` from inside the class:

```
class Car(object):
   def __init__(self):
       self.name = input("What name do you want")

first_car = Car()
```

Comment: A better method would be to separate the  input into a class method - see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/q/24986072/3001761

Comment: @jonrsharpe yes, that it would (added to my answer). @ ufo: protip, you can accept answers to mark the question as answered by checking the green check mark.