# Example of Class with User Input

Tags: python, class, python-2.7, instance

In most of the examples I have seen online while (trying to) learn classes, the instances of the classes are defined by the programmer. Are there any ways of creating an instance of a class where it the variable that stores the class is defined by the user?

This is an example of an object from another SO question:

```
class StackOverflowUser:
    def __init__(self, name, userid, rep): 
        self.name = name
        self.userid = userid
        self.rep = rep

dave = StackOverflowUser("Dave Webb",3171,500)
```

How can this be changed so that the user can create instances based off of the class?

Comment: Why do you think the user can't *currently* *"create instance based off of [sic] the class"*? What kind of user? Do you mean taking input from the terminal (see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/q/24986072/3001761)?

Comment: Why does the `StackOverflowUser` instance for Dave _need_ to be named `dave`? An instance doesn't even need a name, eg if you have a `list` or `dict` of instances.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are broadly two ways of doing it, either:

1. Have the input entirely outside the class, and just pass it in to `__init__` as normal:

   ```
   user = StackOverflowUser(
       raw_input('Name: '),
       int(raw_input('User ID: ')), 
       int(raw_input('Reputation: ')),
   )
   ```

   which is arguably a simpler concept; or
2. Take input within the class, e.g. using a class method:

   ```
   class StackOverflowUser:

       def __init__(self, name, userid, rep): 
           self.name = name
           self.userid = userid
           self.rep = rep

       @classmethod
       def from_input(cls):
           return cls(
               raw_input('Name: '),
               int(raw_input('User ID: ')), 
               int(raw_input('Reputation: ')),
           )
   ```

   then call it like:

   ```
   user = StackOverflowUser.from_input()
   ```

I prefer the latter, as it keeps the necessary input logic with the class it belongs to, and note that neither currently has any validation of the input (see e.g. [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23294658/3001761)).

---

If you want to have multiple users, you could hold them in a dictionary using a unique key (e.g. their `userid` - note that Stack Overflow allows multiple users to have the same name, so that *wouldn't* be unique):

```
users = {}
for _ in range(10):  # create 10 users
    user = StackOverflowUser.from_input()  # from user input
    users[user.userid] = user  # and store them in the dictionary
```

Then each user is accessible as `users[id_of_user]`. You could add a check to reject users with duplicate IDs as follows:

```
if user.userid in users:
    raise ValueError('duplicate ID')
```

Comment: I'm trying to do this `return cls(...) if flag == 1 else cls(...)` , "..." are different inputs, the `if-else` aren't working in `from_input()` function return stmts. control simply jumps to `else` part. Do you know why?

Comment: @anu how could I possibly guess? Presumably `flag != 1`, but I don't know where that value is coming from.

Comment: here, is the code snippet! `@classmethod
    def from_input(cls):
        flag = input("Press 1 || 2 \n")
  
        print(flag)
        return cls(
            input('Name: '),
            int(input('User ID: ')),
            int(input('Reputation: '))) if flag ==1 else cls(
                                    input('Name1: '),
                                    int(input('User ID1: ')), 
                                    int(input('Reputation1: ')))`, I am taking flag as another input in the `from_input ()`, it is like, if user press 1 do this and if user press 2 do that.

Answer (score 4):

Take input and store them in variables and use them to create the instance

```
 class StackOverflowUser:
        def __init__(self, name, userid, rep): 
            self.name = name
            self.userid = userid
            self.rep = rep

 name = raw_input("Enter name: ")
 userid = int(raw_input("Enter user id: "))
 rep = int(raw_input("Enter rep: "))

 dave = StackOverflowUser(name, userid, rep)
```

Comment: @silentphoenix how is this **not** the user creating an instance themselves? What are you *actually trying to achieve?!*

Comment: @silentphoenix But we cannot answer questions that we don't understand, which makes this a waste of everyone's time. It's still not clear what difference you see between *"the instance, not just the attributes"* - the attributes **define** the instance. Try to articulate clearly what you're asking, e.g. by providing examples of how you would use the functionality once you'd implemented it.

Comment: @silentphoenix

1. To create the instance from command line
`from user.py import StackOverflowUser`
`user = StackOverflowUser(name_here, userid_here, rep_here)`
Is this what you wanted?

Comment: @silentphoenix: If you want multiple instances then put them in a list or a dictionary.

Comment: _"what if the user is not named dave?"_. Then the code will still work. You could change your variable name to `user` or `foo` or `___` and it should still operate the same way. The variable name should not contain the name of the user; that is what the `name` attribute is for.