# Input, test, and output per instance in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I hope this question makes sense, I have been literally trying to figure this out for two complete days.

I am trying to create a very small script, which I can then convert into a Flask web app, for comparing SPECint processor scores.

A bit of background:

From specint.org, I can download csv files containing benchmark information about processors and servers they have benchmarked.  The idea of my app is to do the following:

1. Ask users for the benchmark they need (cint or rint), the server
   model, and the processor they're interested in. This must be done
   twice, for server 1 and server 2 so I can compare them.
2. I need to check that the information they are entering is correct,
   i.e. if someone enters as processor name XYZ it should raise an
   error and prompt for entering a valid query. For this, I'm planning
   to dump a version of the whole database into my own database, so I
   can perform the check before actually downloading the csv file from
   the server.
3. If the information entered is valid, I would dynamically generate the correct url for downloading and reading the csv file containing the benchmark score information, directly from SPECint's server.
4. Once I have downloaded and processed the information for both servers, I would apply some simple math and return the results saying something like this:  "Server 1 is 10% faster/slower than server 2", or something like that.

As you probably imagine, this will require a lot of duplicated code, so it seems it's the perfect use-case for a class.  I have been performing some tests, and the results are promising.

However, my issue is that I have not been able to figure out how to capture the user inputs, test the inputs, download the corresponding csv file, and pass the user inputs all on a per-instance fashion, without having to duplicate code somewhere.  I have been searching and searching, and it seems a `@classmethod` is what I need, but I'm not sure since the use of it still seems quite esoteric to me (I'm a newbie) (ref: [Example of Class with User Input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32721580/example-of-class-with-user-input))

For example, this is kinda working:

My class:

```
class Baseline:
    def __init__(self, benchmark, model, processor):
        self.benchmark = benchmark
        self.model = model
        self.processor = processor
```

Capturing and printing instance results.

```
old_server = inputs.Baseline(test=input("Select benchmark: "),
                             model=input("Enter model: "),
                             processor=input("Enter processor: ")
                             )
new_server = inputs.Baseline(test=input("Select benchmark: "),
                             model=input("Enter model: "),
                             processor=input("Enter processor: ")
                             )

print(old_server.benchmark)
print(old_server.model)
print(new_server.benchmark)
print(new_server.model)
```

As you can see, I'm already repeating code, and instead, I'd like to do everything from within the class, so I can simply call instances of it to both capture, test, download, and return the results.  As I said earlier, it seems that `@classmethod`is the answer, but I'd appreciate any guidance, hopefully with a bit of sample code so I can fully grasp the concepts.

Answer (score 0):

It was a long question so I hope I followed your drift correctly, If I did you can do something like:

```
class BaseLine(object):
    @classmethod
    def run(cls):
        benchmark = raw_input('Enter benchmark please: ')
        model = raw_input('Enter model please: ')
        processor = raw_input('Enter processor please: ')

        yes_no = raw_input('you picked %s, %s, %s - are you sure? (y/n) ' % (benchmark, model, processor))

        if yes_no.lower() == 'y':
            print('Great Sucess!')
            return benchmark, model, processor
        else:
            return cls.run()
```

Where your main would be something like:

```
benchmark1, model1, processor1 = BaseLine.run()
benchmark2, model2, processor2 = BaseLine.run()
```

This is a simplified case and depending on the checks you do and how you structure your code you should design if to use a classmethod or an instance method (self). If your instance has a state and your equivalent to `run` uses that state (connection with DB for instance) then it should be an instance method instead.

Comment: Cheers Uri.  I will try this, and @nutmeg64's answer as well and check which one fits my use case best.  I'll report back once I figure it all out :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
class Baseline:
    def __init__(self):
        self.benchmark = input("Select benchmark: ")
        self.model = input("Enter model: ")
        self.processor = input("Enter processor: ")
```

Which will make your code less duplicated as creating new instances will be:

```
old_server = inputs.Baseline()
new_server = inputs.Baseline()
```

*Side note* you can also implement the `__str__` method to print it all out:

```
def __str__(self):
    return '\n'.join(str(item) for item in self.__dict__.values())
```

And then printing is easy:

```
print(old_server)
```

As a general advice I wouldn't count on a user's "free" input for processor models and benchmarks since most of the time it contains a mixture of lowercase, uppercase numbers etc.

What I would do, especially because you said you want to use `Flask` (so thats going to be more simple), is narrow it down to the processor models and benchmarks you support only. Implementation-wise this means a *drop-down* list on your application and a `set` or `list` of the models, benchmarks etc. This will also save you the trouble of *input validation*.

In the case that not all of the models go with all of the benchmarks you can use `dict` to do some book-keeping. **But** if the book-keeping is getting complicated, consider using `class`es for "automatic" book-keeping.
Those classes can then be `pickled`, `jsonified` and other methods for saving them into databases.

If you share more code, we could help a little bit more.
In any case, I suggest you post this question on [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) for deeper analysis.

Comment: This makes a lot of sense.  I will try the code and read a bit about what you suggest.  I don't have more code to share, unfortunately, pretty much the only code missing so far is the csv reader function.  I especially like your suggestion for the implementation, since I'll need that.  Creating a dropdown for all options is not really feasible, since they are too many, but dividing them as you suggest is a very good idea.  I'm a newbie, so I'll have to do some homework here.  Once I have something at least half-functional, I'll submit it to code review.  Cheers!