# Asking the user about the radius of the circle and will solve the area and the circumference

Tags: python, class, oop

I am making a class similar code to this but I don't know how I will make it into a input function.

How would I ask the user to input a radius of a circle?

```
class Circle:
    def __init__(self, r):
        self.radius = r
    def area(self):
        return 3.14 * (self.radius ** 2)
    def perimeter(self):
        return 2*3.14*self.radius
obj = Circle(3)
print("Area of circle:",obj.area())
print("Perimeter of circle:",obj.perimeter())
```

Comment: `obj = Circle(int(input("Enter Radius:")))`

Comment: There is a function "input" (for Python 3.x) to retrieve input from the user. Or what exactly is the problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Example of Class with User Input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32721580/example-of-class-with-user-input)

Comment: thanks @kpie I am close to that actually, but I didn't know I can place the "Circle" there

Answer (score 3):

You just have to replace the argument to an input function to take input from the user. So the code will be changed from

```
obj = Circle(3)
```

to

```
obj = Circle(int(input("Please Enter Radius:")))
```

The `int()` before the input function is to convert the input from string to an integer.
To know more about taking input from user, please check out [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/taking-input-in-python/).

Comment: You're welcome. Keep learning and have fun. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
class Circle:
    def __init__(self, r):
        self.radius = r
    def area(self):
        return 3.14 * (self.radius ** 2)
    def perimeter(self):
        return 2*3.14*self.radius
obj = Circle(int(input("Enter Radius:")))
#obj = Circle()
print("Area of circle:",obj.area())
print("Perimeter of circle:",obj.perimeter())
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).