# use of @attr in python inside a class

Tags: python

I am going through open-stack Tempest code. I see some syntax @ used inside a class as below. Could some one give me a proper link where i can learn above why this @ is used.

```
  @classmethod
      def setUpClass(cls):
      cls.set_network_resources()
      super(TestLargeOpsScenario, cls).setUpClass()
```

or even like this,

```
  @attr(type='smoke')
  def test_update_setver_name(self):
        name = rand_server('server')
```

so what is the use of @ over here?

Comment: There are decorators. Loads of article available on it. http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0318/

Comment: no pointing in down voting a question like this.  questions like this actually helps people to get work done fast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the python docs:

[Python Doc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#classmethod)

Or a previous stackoverflow question:

[Previously answered question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12179271/python-classmethod-and-staticmethod-for-beginner)

Answer (score 0):

@attr , decorator DP.
More for good understanding of Decorator DP, examples at:
http://thecodeship.com/patterns/guide-to-python-function-decorators/