# How to present a class as a function?

Tags: python, django, function, oop, python-rq

As it was unclear earlier I am posting this scenario:

```
class Scraper:
    def __init__(self,url):
      self.start_page = url

    def parse_html(self):
      pass

    def get_all_links(self):
      pass

    def run(self):
      #parse html, get all links, parse them and when done...
      return links
```

Now in a task queue like rq

```
from rq import Queue
from worker import conn

q = Queue(connection=conn)
result = q.enqueue(what_function, 'http://stackoverflow.com')
```

I want to know what this what_function would be? I remembered Django does something similar with their CBVs so I used that analogy but it wasn't so clear.

---

I have a class like

```
class A:
    def run(self,arg):
        #do something
```

I need to past this to a task queue, so I can do something like

```
a = A()
b = a.run
# q is the queue object
q.enqueue(b,some_arg)
```

I'd want to know what other method is there to do this, for example, Django does it in their Class Based Views,

```
class YourListView(ListView):
    #code for your view
```

which is eventually passed as a function

```
your_view = YourListView.as_view()
```

How is it done?

Edit: to elaborate, django's class based views are converted to functions because the argument in the pattern function expects a function. Similarly, you might have a function which accepts the following argument

```
task_queue(callback_function, *parameters):
    #add to queue and return result when done
```

but the functionality of callback_function might have been mostly implemented in a class, which has a run() method via which the process is ran.

Comment: What do you mean, "present a class as a function?"

Comment: I don't understand your question.  Your two code examples don't look anything alike.  Please clarify what you actually want to do.

Comment: @AaronHall some functions, like the task queue in rq, expect a function as the argument. However if you have written most of your code in oop, you might want to finally present it as a function to be able to pass it into the queue

Comment: Note that a class is already a *callable* in Python; when called, it produces an object of the class.

Comment: does my answer seem to address what you're asking?

Comment: I think what you are looking for is a class method. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12179271/python-classmethod-and-staticmethod-for-beginner) and if that's not it, come back and add some more details.

Comment: @yayu I think I fully answered you. Please accept if I did.

Comment: @AaronHall yes, I think so. I am just wrapping my mind around how to use  class methods for my case. Thanks. I have accepted your answer.

Comment: @AaronHall oh you just spoonfed me the answer as well!! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're describing a `classmethod`:

```
class MyClass(object):
    @classmethod
    def as_view(cls):
        '''method intended to be called on the class, not an instance'''
        return cls(instantiation, args)
```

which could be used like this:

```
call_later = MyClass.as_view
```

and later called:

```
call_later()
```

Most frequently, class methods are used to instantiate a new instance, for example, `dict`'s `fromkeys` classmethod:

```
dict.fromkeys(['foo', 'bar'])
```

returns a new dict instance:

```
{'foo': None, 'bar': None}
```

#### Update

In your example,

```
result = q.enqueue(what_function, 'http://stackoverflow.com')
```

you want to know `what_function` could go there. I saw a very similar example from the RQ home page. That's got to be your own implementation. It's going to be something you can call with your code. It's only going to be called with that argument once, so if using a class, your `__init__` should look more like this, if you want to use `Scraper` for your `what_function` replacement:

```
class Scraper:
    def __init__(self,url):
        self.start_page = url
        self.run()
        # etc...
```

If you want to use a class method, that might look like this:

```
class Scraper:
    def __init__(self,url):
        self.start_page = url

    def parse_html(self):
        pass

    def get_all_links(self):
        pass

    @classmethod
    def run(cls, url):
        instance = cls(url)
        #parse html, get all links, parse them and when done...
        return links
```

And then  your `what_function` would be `Scraper.run`.

Comment: Ok, suppose `MyClass` has an attribute `val`  and I have two objects, `a = Myclass('a')` and `b = Myclass('b')` such that `a.val = 'a'` and `b.val='b'` now, if the class method is using the val attribute of the class, which one would it use?

Comment: @yayu neither, there would be an AttributeError unless you provide a class variable to the class namespace, for example, immediately under `class MyClass(object):` you have `val = None` or some other value that puts the variable `val` in the classes' namespace.