# Creating a class that inherits from dict using a txtfile - python

Tags: python, class, object, dictionary

I have a file as such:

```
1 23
2 21
5 23
561 2
73 19781
```

And with this function:

```
def readx(x):
    return {int(line.split()[0]):int(line.split()[1]) for line in x.split('\n')}
```

I can get this:

```
{1: 23, 2: 21, 5: 23, 73: 19781, 561: 2}
```

But I need to put it into some sort of class object, so I tried this:

```
z = """1 23
2 21
5 23
561 2
73 19781"""

def readx(x):
    return {int(line.split()[0]):int(line.split()[1]) for line in x.split('\n')}


class Foo(dict):
    def __init__(self, x):
        self = readx(x)

f = Foo(z)
print f
```

But it returns a None instead of the dictionary.

1. **Is there a more pythonic way to do `readx()`?** It a little ugly as it is now.
2. **How do i get the class object to work and make `foo` a dict with keys and values?**

Comment: Actually this `{1: 23, 2: 21, 5: 23, 73: 19781, 561: 2}` is already "some sort of class object", isn't it? It's an instance of `dict`

Comment: @alvas try to do `for k,v in readx(x).items(): self[k] = v`...

Comment: in your constructor use self.__x = readx(x) and a property to your class to access the variable self.__x

Comment: @DominikNeise, it is but it doesn't solve the problem and I want to build a class object from it. let's say i want to call a function to return a function in `__init__()` (it is more complicated than readx()).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To the first question, yes, this comprehension is a bit unreadable, a simple loop might work better:

```
def read_dict(fp):
   d = {}
   for line in fp:
        k, v = line.strip().split();
        d[int(k)] = int(v)
   return d
```

where `fp` is any iterable, e.g. a file object.

To the second question, if your `__init__` doesn't do any useful job, just get rid of it, and pass the result of `read` as an argument to the constructor, which will then transparently invoke the parent `dict.__init__`:

```
class Foo(dict):
    # stuff

with open(path) as fp:
   foo = Foo(read_dict(fp))
```

Alternatively, instantiate Foo right in `read` and return it:

```
 def read_foo(fp):
   d = Foo()
   for line in fp:
       # etc, just as above
```

and then simply

```
with open(path) as fp:
   foo = read_foo(fp)
```

You can also make `read` a class method in Foo to structure your code better:

```
class Foo(dict):

   @classmethod
   def read(cls, fp):
       d = cls()
       for line in fp:
          #etc
```

and then:

```
with open(path) as fp:
   foo = Foo.read(fp)
```

Finally, if you want to initialize Foo directly from the `fp` object, you do need `__init__`:

```
class Foo(dict):
    def __init__(self, fp):
        for line in fp:
            k, v = line.strip().split()
            self[int(k)] = int(v)
```

and then

```
x = Foo(fp)
```

This code should be used with care though, since it violates the [Liskov substitution principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle), and that is generally not a good thing.

Comment: +1 for the class method. By building the structure inline, we eliminate the overhead of an extra copy.

Comment: but the `Foo` will be `type<dict>` and not a Foo object right? So if i want to put more methods into Foo and `foo` needs to access it, would it still be possible? or is it like putting everything outside as normal `def` functions?

Comment: @alvas: no, if you do `x=Foo(whatever)`, `x` will be `type Foo`, no matter if you have `__init__` or not.

Comment: ooooo. So when i do `foo = Foo.read(fp)`, foo is of a Foo object?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12179271/python-classmethod-and-staticmethod-for-beginner

Comment: @alvas: yes, because `Foo.read` does `d=cls()`, which is basically the same as `d=Foo()` (first argument to a class method is the class itself).

Comment: Is there a way such that I use `foo = Foo(fp)` instead `foo = Foo.read(fp)`?

Comment: Once again, thanks a million and noted on the Liskov!

Answer (score 3):

Use [`super`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/576169/understanding-python-super-and-init-methods):

```
class Foo(dict):
    def __init__(self, x):
        super(Foo, self).__init__(readx(x))
```

This will call the `dict` constructor on the data, copying it into the object.

Note that this works on Python 3 as well.

Comment: is there a reason why super() is necessary?

Comment: It's not necessary in this case; you can use `dict.__init__(self, readx(x))` instead if you want to. But since there are other cases where it *does* matter, we might as well make a habit of using `super` now.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative without `super` is:

```
class Foo(dict):
    def __init__(self, x):
        for k, v in readx(x).items():
            self[k] = v
```

Comment: but that would mean that i would need to iterate through the keys twice, once for readx() and once for the init, right?

Comment: @alvas I think we end up iterating twice either way, since the `dict` constructor makes a copy.

Comment: @alvas you are copying the content of the dictionary created by `readx()` into your class using this for loop