# Using raw input inside of a class (python 2.7)

Tags: python

I was wondering how to use raw input inside of a class, so instead of passing the name 'Ryan' we could pass a variable inside of the object and ask for that variable later on.

such as:

```
name = raw_input("What is your name? ")
```

Here is the code I have:

```
class Talk:
        def __init__(self, name):
                self.name = name
                print "Hey there, " + self.name

        def printName(self):
                print self.name

talk = Talk('Ryan')
```

Comment: Can you be a little clearer about what you want? Post the relevant code in the question and give some example input/output

Answer (score 3):

Typically, this would be done with a [*class method*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12179271/3001761), separating the user input (and any associated validation) from the `__init__` of the new instance:

```
class Talk(object):

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        print "Hey there, {}".format(self.name)

    def print_name(self):
        print self.name

    @classmethod
    def from_input(cls):
        """Create a new Talk instance from user input."""
        while True:
            name = raw_input("Enter your name: ")
            if name:
                return cls(name)
```

Which would be used like:

```
>>> talk = Talk.from_input()
Enter your name: Ryan
Hey there, Ryan
>>> talk.print_name()
Ryan
```

Note that I have renamed `printName` to `print_name`, per the [style guide](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). Also, it would be conventional to **not** `print` from inside `__init__`, and provide `__str__` and `__repr__` methods rather than a `print_name` (see Python's [data model documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html) for more information).

Answer (score 0):

You can call functions inside class methods. These methods include `__init__`. For example:

```
class Talk:
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = raw_input("What is your name: ")
        print "Hey there, " + self.name

    def printName(self):
        print self.name

talk = Talk()
```