# How to call function of class A in class B inside python script?

Tags: python, class, object

I have a python script consisting of two classes in which i want to call function of one class inside function of another class. The structure look something as follows:

```
class A():
    def funct(arg1, arg2):
         B.other(arg)
         ....            
class B():
    def other(arg):
        ....
```

So , please help me how will i call function of class B inside class A funct?

Comment: you must to instanciate B and declare static the **other** method.

PD: where is the **cls** argument?

Also you can look an eye to this: http://www.jesshamrick.com/2011/05/18/an-introduction-to-classes-and-inheritance-in-python/

Comment: Highly related (and maybe duplicate of) [What is the difference between staticmethod and classmethod in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/136097/what-is-the-difference-between-staticmethod-and-classmethod-in-python). Also you can check [Python classmethod and staticmethod for beginner?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12179271/python-classmethod-and-staticmethod-for-beginner)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
class A():
    def funct(self, arg1, arg2):
        B().other(arg1)

class B():
    def other(self, arg):
        print "inside other"

A().funct('arg1','arg2')
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it in 2 ways

1. Through object creation : if you want to use the methods of class A in class B, then create object A inside class B like `obj = A()` and call the methods using the reference variable obj like `obj.function()`.
2. Through inheritance: define class be like `class B(A)` and after that you can use all methods of class A inside class B

Answer (score 0):

Define B's method as a @classmethod:

```
    class A(object):
        def funct(self, arg1, arg2):
            B.other(arg1)

    class B(object):
        @classmethod
        def other(cls, arg1):
            print "In B: " + arg1

    A().funct("arg", "arg2")
```

Answer (score -1):

Use classmethod:

```
class B(object):

    @classmethod
    def other(cls, arg1, arg2):
        print "I am function class B"

class A(object):
    def funct(self, arg1, arg2):
         B.other(arg1, arg2)

A().funct(1,2)

===>I am function class B
```

Use staticmethod:

```
class B(object):

    @staticmethod
    def other(arg1, arg2):
        print "I am function class B"

class A(object):
    def funct(self, arg1, arg2):
         B.other(arg1, arg2)

A().funct(1,2)

===>I am function class B
```

Some [references](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12179271/python-classmethod-and-staticmethod-for-beginner) about staticmethod and classmethod.

Instantiate B inside A class

```
class B(object):
    def other(self, arg1, arg2):
        print "I am function class B"

class A(object):
    def funct(self, arg1, arg2):
         B().other(arg1, arg2)

A().funct(1,2)
===>I am function class B
```

You could use Python Inheritance.

```
    class B(object):
        def other(self, arg=None):
            print "I am function class B"

    class A(B):
        def funct(self, arg1, arg2):
             self.other()

    a_class_object = A()
    a_class_object.other()

===>I am function class B
```

Also din't forgive to add `self` argument to class methods.
You can find out more information about Inheritance in off. Python [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html)