# access object members from dynamically added methods in python

Tags: python, reflection, metaprogramming

I have problem sharing members of a class with its dynamically generated methods.

For example below `x` accessed from `__init__` and from `normal_test` is different fro `x` accessed from dynamically bounded methods `test` and `setx`:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 10
    def normal_test(self):
        print self.x

def bar(self):
    print self.x
def setx_method(self,x):
    self.x = x

setattr(Foo, "test", classmethod(bar))
setattr(Foo, "setx", classmethod(setx_method))

f = Foo();
f.setx(5)
f.test()
f.normal_test()
```

How should I write the code such that `self.x` would refer to same `x`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Analyzing

```
setattr(Foo, "setx", classmethod(setx_method))
```

It's equivalent to

```
@classmethod
def setx_method(self,x):
    self.x=x
```

Now when you invoke `f.setx(5)`, it actually binds `f`'s `class(ie, Foo)` with self and 5 with `x` and thus it executed `Foo.x = 5`

In short you have two `x` in `Foo`, one is instance member `x` and one is class member `x`.

```
f.setx(5)        # sets class x
f.test()         # print class variable x
f.normal_test()  # print instance variable x
```

Comment: Thanks I failed to understand that setting an attribute method on class actually defined a method.. no need of class method.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use `@classmethod` with `self`, because it points to your class instance, while in `@classmethod` you should use `cls` as it points to whole your class.

See here: [Meaning of @classmethod and @staticmethod for beginner?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12179271/python-classmethod-and-staticmethod-for-beginner)

---

So the simplest solution is just remove `classmethod`:

```
setattr(Foo, "test", bar)
setattr(Foo, "setx", setx_method)
```