# How to call value of a function from a class in python?

Tags: python, function, python-2.7

I have a file `x.py` and another file `y.py`

I have a class `x` in `x.py` and it has a function defined as:

```
@property
def x(self):
    return self._x

@x.setter
def x(self, x):
    self.update_x(x)

def xy(self, l):
    self._x = 100
```

Now I want to use this value in the other file `y.py`

Where I have:

```
from models.x import X # where X is the name of the class in  x.py

def functionX(self):
    y = # set this value as the value of x in function x from x.py
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Well, you'd need to create an instance of `X` before you can access its non-static methods... Can I also suggest using less confusing names? A class named `X` (or is it `x`? You used it both ways.) in a file named `x` that has a function named `x` that returns `_x` is not exactly easy to comprehend at first glance.

Comment: This doesn't make sense. The class X doesn't have a value for x; it's a property, which has a value for a particular *instance* of X.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The class doesn't have a property `x`. What it *does* have is a property method `x`, and methods are only callable on instances (mostly. you can check out [class methods and static methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12179271/python-classmethod-and-staticmethod-for-beginner), but they're not what you want here).

So in `y.py` you need an instance of the class `X`, which you can get by doing something like `foo = X()`. You can then refer to `foo.x`.