# Passing argument between two classes

Tags: python, class, oop

I have a python program with this structure:

```
import sys

class A:
    def __init__(self):
        ...

    def func(self, other, args):
        z = something
        n = B.start(z)
        print n

    def other_funcs(self, some, args):
        ...

class B:
    def __init__(self):
         self.start(z)

    def start(self, z)
         k = something
         return k

if __name__ == '__main__'
    A()
```

When I generate `z` I want to give it to B class and then B returns k for me again.

But the error exists:

```
TypeError: unbound method start() must be called with B instance as first argument (got list instance instead)
```

Comment: shouldn't `self.start(z)` say `z` is not defined?

Answer (score 2):

IIUC, what you're looking for here is [`classmethod`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12179271/python-classmethod-and-staticmethod-for-beginner).

The problem is that you don't have a a `B` object, but rather just the `B` class. You need a method of `B` that takes a class, not an instance. Define `start` like so:

```
@classmethod
def start(cls, z):
```

For example, this runs fine:

```
class A:                                                                                                                                                                                               
     def func(self):                                                          
          n = B.start(0)                                                          


class B:    
     @classmethod                                                                                                                                               
     def start(cls, z):                                                          
          pass                                                                 

if __name__ == '__main__':                                                   
     A().func()
```

Comment: Now the error is: NameError: global name 'B' is not defined

Comment: @MLSC The above runs fine by me. By the way, it's pretty clear the code you posted is not exactly the one you're using, as it has other errors (missing `:`, for example).

Comment: Your indentation is off

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively you can initialize a `B` object:

```
n = B().start(z)
```

However your `__init__` method calls `start` with argument `z` which may not work as `z` is not defined yet.

Comment: Now the error is: `NameError: global name 'B' is not defined`

Comment: Switch places of class B and A in the source (B must be defined before A)

Comment: Again I have that errro. Shouldn;t I import somthing?

Comment: You don't need to import anything as both classes are defined in the same module (ie. same .py file)

Comment: I have done it in same .py and switched the classes. but problem exists

Comment: Please update your question with your new code, and new error message including full stack trace; or post another question.

Answer (score 1):

You can modify `__init__` of class `B` to take an argument which passes `z` to it.

```
class B:
    __init__(self, z): #Pass 'z' when you create an object a 'class B' in 'class A'
```

There are some problems with your code.

You need to understand what a `constructor` is and when it gets called. You have

```
if __name__ == '__main__': # Fixed missing colon here
    A()
```

This only calls the `__init__` function of `class A`.

You need to use something like

```
A().func() # Pass required arguments here
```

The proper way to use methods in classes is to create objects (however not required for class methods). In your `class A` you have

```
n = B.start(z) # Line in func() of class A
```

This doesn't work.

You need to call `B()` with required arguments for `__init__` in `class B` and not simply `B`.

Example code passing message from `class A` and printing it from `class B`:

```
class foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.var1 = "I'm from class A"
        bar(self.var1)


class bar:
    def __init__(self, var):
        print(var)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    foo()
```