# Trying to create a object from a class by calling a function

Tags: python, function, class

I am working on a project that I need to create some objects dynamically from a class. I am not asking for anyone to solve it but just point me in the right direction. An example would be if I was working with Dogs.

```
class Dog(object):
    """Creating Dogs"""
    def __init__(self, name, age, gender):
        super(Dog, self).__init__()
        self.name = name
        self.name = age
        self.name = gender
```

I would like however to have a function that I can pass this information into that would create a global object. The function would look like this:

```
def create_dog(name, age, gender):
    name = Dog(name,age, gender)
    return(name)
```

So theoretically if I passed the name "Jack" to the function I would have a object globally called "Jack" from the class. I am just trying to find a good way to do this if any. If this is completely against python I will figure out another way but I am sitting here stuck. I have also thought about nesting the class within my function but the namespace won't go into global.

Comment: Is there a reason for having a bunch of global objects? Generally it's best to avoid global objects when possible because the code can become very difficult to debug.

Comment: Not 100% sure what you're asking, but possible duplicate of [How do I do variable variables in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1373164/953482). Short version: it's almost never a good idea to have a function `create_dog("Jack", 5, "male")` that creates a variable in the global scope whose name is `Jack`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could create a global dictionary

```
dogs = {}

def create_dog(name, age, gender):
    # maybe check if already exists
    dogs[name] = Dog(name, age, gender)
```

Comment: I started to lean towards this as well as it is cleaner and not having to deal with "leaking" between namespaces per se.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to make an alternative constructor ?

```
class Dog(object):
    """Creating Dogs"""
    def __init__(self, name, age, gender):
        super(Dog, self).__init__()
        self.name = name
        self.name = age
        self.name = gender


   @classmethod
   def create_dog(name, age, gender):
       name = Dog(name,age, gender)
       return name
```

See also discussion [Meaning of @classmethod and @staticmethod for beginner?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12179271/python-classmethod-and-staticmethod-for-beginner)

A global dictionary is fine if you use a single file script, but for a more complex software you'll have to import all the 3 elements:

```
 from dogs import dogs, create_dog, Dog
```

With class attribute you import just one name space. So you could do this:

```
class Dog(object):
    """Creating Dogs"""

    members = []

    def __init__(self, name, age, gender):
        super(Dog, self).__init__()
        self.name = name
        self.name = age
        self.name = gender


   @classmethod
   def create_dog(name, age, gender):
       name = Dog(name,age, gender)
       Dog.members.append(name)
       return name
```

Now you can simply `import Dog`, and access the class attribute `Dog.members`

Comment: Thanks Oz. I am definitely going to read much more on this. I think I am going to lean towards to the dictionary for this instance, but I have ran into this question a couple of times.

Comment: you could modify the constructor to update the class, and the you don't have a global variable rather a class attribute.

Answer (score 0):

With changing *locals*: (which is still bad, but not as much as changing *globals*)

```
def create_dog(name, age, gender, locals_=locals()):
    dog = Dog(name, age, gender)
    locals_[name] = dog


create_dog("jack", 3, "male")
print(jack)
```

Comment: Thank you sir for the hint.