# How to return a class instance in member function of a class?

Tags: python-2.7, function, class, instance, return-type

I want to return a class instance in member function of a class, my code is:

```
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        [snippet]

    def func(self, *args, **kwargs):
        [snippet]
        return class_instnace_of_MyClass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    obj = MyClass(...)
    newobj = obj.func(...)  # type(newobj) is MyClass
```

I think I can call `__init__()` in `func()`, and return a new instance of MyClass, but I don't think it is a Pythonic way to do so. How should I do that? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel like you should use the `@classmethod` decorator for this, if I'm reading your question right. Something like:

```
class myClass(object):

    def __int__(name):
        self.name = name

    @classmethod
    def from_fancy(cls, name):
        #do something with name, maybe make it 
        #lowercase or something...
        return cls(name)
```

For example, in the `pandas` package you can create a `DateFrame` object by doing things like `pandas.DataFrame.from_csv(...)` or `pandas.DataFrame.from_json(...)`. Each of those are class methods which return a `DataFrame` object, created with different initial data sets (csv text file or a JSON text file).

For instance, you would call it like:

```
my_new_object = myClass.from_fancy("hello world")
```

There's a good thread on `@classmethod` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12179271/python-classmethod-and-staticmethod-for-beginner)

Comment: unnecessary, the magic in @classicmethod will take care of it, at least in python 2.x. Don't know about python 3.x

Comment: @AlexanderYau you don't do anything. Just use the code right there. Nothing else. Welcome to the simplicity of python, you'll have to get used to it.

Comment: @AlexanderYau make sure you really need this: can't you just extend `__init__`? the proper way to create an object in python is to use `__init__`. all methods in python are public

Comment: Thank you, @classmethod works fine. One more question, is instance attribute can be used in @classmethod?

Comment: Not sure what you mean?

Answer (score 2):

`__init__` is the class' constructor in Python. In no cases does it return anything, meaning its value is `None`. It is futile to pass an argument to `func()` that is empty. Your assumption is true, that is not the Pythonic way to create another instance of `MyClass`.

If you want to create a new instance of `MyClass` just do this:

```
obj = MyClass(...) # First instance
newobj = MyClass(...) # Add another instance
```

Read more on class objects and their instantiation [**here**](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html).

Answer (score 2):

To `return` a new instance from a method, instantiate the class in the method, and return that new instance, like so:

```
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        pass

    def func(self, *args, **kwargs):
        ...
        return MyClass(...)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    obj = MyClass(...)
    newobj = obj.func(...)
```

Or instead of the *merry-go-round*, you could just `newobj = MyClass(...)`