# Python: Call a class method from within a 'DIFFERENT class''s method

Tags: python, oop

I want to call a method from classB, in a method in classA and pass arguments:

```
class A:
     B.processAds(ad, cnx, renewableAds, adsToRenew, webdriver)


class B:
    def processAds(self, ad, cnx, renewableAds, adsToRenew, webdriver):
```

How would I do this?

Comment: you have to initialize an instance of class B (`foo = B()`) first and use it in class A (`foo.some_method_from_A(args)`).

Comment: How does `class B` know which instance of `class A` is to be used? Is that passed on instance initialization or in the method call itself? An example runnable script without so many parameters would only be a dozen lines long. How about fleshing this out a bit?

Answer (score 0):

Make the method in class B a `classmethod`:

```
class B:
    @classmethod
    def processAds(cls, ad, cnx, renewableAds, adsToRenew, webdriver):
```

then you'll be able to use it without instantiating class B, e.g.:

```
return_value = B.processAds(ad, cnx, renewableAds, adsToRenew, webdriver)
```

You can read more about `classmethod` in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12179752/3570352).

Comment: I don't think there is enough information in the question to conclude that a class method will work. OP clearly shows that `processAds` is an instance method.