# how to change the value of a global varible in the child classe of python?

Tags: python, django, inheritance

I have a problem in declaring variable in the child class. I have simplified the case because the code is too long and have many dependencies. So here is the case :

I have 2 classes `A` and `B` :

```
 class A ():
     global_var=0
     def some_function(self):
          return self.global_var+2

 class B(A):

      def method_that_returns_global_var(self):
           #do some operations on global_var
           global_var=(.....some logic....)
           return global_var
```

How to declare the `global_var` in the child class `B` so that it executes the function of the parent class `some_function` with the value of global_var of child class `B`

Comment: PS : please when down voting , explain to us as newbies why :'(
or at least say that it's impossible or python don't permit that !!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So... There's a couple of concepts that you should probably clarify.

That `global_var` is not a *global* variable. It's a *class* attribute. It means it's only defined once: When you declare the class. After that, all the classes of the same type (or their inherited classes) will share **the same** variable. I found [this](https://docs.python.org/2.7/tutorial/classes.html#class-and-instance-variables), which is probably helpful.

That means that **all** the instances of type `A` or of any type inheriting from `A` (namely `B` in the example) that you create will share it. However, you still need to access them through `self` or through the `cls` (usually the `class` instance is named like that in [classmethods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12179271/python-classmethod-and-staticmethod-for-beginner)) What you're doing in this method...

```
def method_that_returns_global_var(self):
   #do some operations on global_var
   global_var=(.....some logic....)
```

... is just creating a `global_var` variable local to the `method_that_returns_global_var` method (and has nothing to do with the `global_var` in the class)

If it helps you *see it* (it certainly helps me), you can think of that `global_var` as attached to the `class`, not to the **instances** of that class.

This means that class `B` already has access to `global_var` because it inherits from `A`. When you try to access `global_var` in an instance method (the ones that you pass `self` to, broadly speaking), what the interpreter is gonna try to do is find the `global_var` attribute among the ones of the instance (`self`). If it doesn't find it it will go to the class.  **However** (very important) when you *assign* in an instance method (you do `self.global_var = whatever`), the interpreter will just place `global_var` in the **instance** (in its "internal" dictionary of attributes `__dict__`) Don't let that confuse you!

See this:

```
class A(object):
    global_var = 5

    def some_function(self):
        return self.global_var + 2

    def print_global_bar(self):
        print("Global bar value=%s" % self.global_var)


class B(A):
    def method_that_returns_global_var(self):
        # do some operations on global_var
        self.global_var = 1000
        return self.global_var


if __name__ == "__main__":
    b = B()
    b.print_global_bar()
    b.method_that_returns_global_var()
    b.print_global_bar()
    print("Because `method_that_returns_global_var` does an ASSIGNMENT, now I have two `global_var`."
          " One in the class, one in the instance `b`")
    print("In the instance: %s" % b.global_var)
    print("In  the class: %s" % b.__class__.global_var)
```

It outputs:

```
Global bar value=5
Global bar value=1000
Because `method_that_returns_global_var` does an ASSIGNMENT, now I have two `global_var`. One in the class, one in the instance `b`
In the instance: 1000
In  the class: 5
```

If you wanted to do the assignment to the class variable in `method_that_returns_global_var` you should either do it a class method (with the `@classmethod` decorator) or access the class of the instance (located in `self.__class__`)

See now:

```
class A(object):
    global_var = 5

    def some_function(self):
        return self.global_var + 2

    def print_global_bar(self):
        print("Global bar value=%s" % self.global_var)


class B(A):
    def method_that_returns_global_var(self):
        # do some operations on global_var
        self.__class__.global_var = 1000
        return self.global_var


if __name__ == "__main__":
    b = B()
    b.print_global_bar()
    b.method_that_returns_global_var()
    b.print_global_bar()
    print("In the instance: %s" % b.global_var)
    print("In  the class: %s" % b.__class__.global_var)
```

Outputs:

```
Global bar value=5
Global bar value=1000
In the instance: 1000
In  the class: 1000
```

See the difference? In the first method, doing `self.global_var = 1000` creates a *new* attribute in the *instance*, disregarding whatever is written in the `class`. Basically, you have two `global_var`s around: One connected to the class (whose value is still `5`), and one connected to the instance (whose value is `1000`). In the second method, you are accessing and modifying all the time the class variable (`A.global_var`)

I recommend you play a bit more with this... More `print`s, more `.__class__`... things like that. **:-)**

Comment: You're welcome. I know it can get a bit tricky **:-)** (and wait until you start learning that a `class` is also an instance of type `type`, haha)... Weeeell... that can be for some other occasion,**;-)**. Have fun coding!

Answer (score 1):

Despite the "global" in the name, variable is actually a class field. You can overwrite it in child class like this (I shortened it to "var"):

```
 class A ():
     var = 0
     def some_function(self):
          return self.var + 2

 class B(A):
     var = 1


 B().some_function()  # =3
```

Answer (score 1):

When you define a variable in the class scope it becomes a class variable. You can refer to it using class name.

```
class A():
    var = 123

print(A.var)
>>> 123
```

This variable will get inherited, so you should be able to do this

```
class B(A):
    pass

print(B.var)
>>> 123
```

and you should be able to override the default in the child class or change its value in the methods

```
class C(A):
    var = 234

    def inc_var(self):
        self.var += 1

print(C.var)
>>> 234
c = C()
c.inc_var()
print(C.var)
>>> 235
```