# Access method variable from other method python

Tags: python

I have a problem accessing client.close() in readholdingregisters() from  closeconnection() in the code below:

```
class EnergyMeter:
    def __init__(self, model, gatewayipaddress, port ,deviceid):
        self.model = model
        self.gatewayipaddress = gatewayipaddress
        self.port = port
        self.deviceid = deviceid

    def readholdingregisters(self, startingregister, numberofregisters):
        from pymodbus3.client.sync import ModbusTcpClient as ModbusClient
        client = ModbusClient(self.gatewayipaddress, port=self.port)
        client.connect()
        if #some code here:
            #some other code here
            return concatResult
        else:
            return otherResult
```

## Here I want to close the connection client.connect() from readholdingregisters():

```
    def closeconnection(self):
        EnergyMeter.readholdingregisters().client.close()??????????????????
```

Can you plase give me a good solution how  to do it?

Comment: Store the connection on the instance just like you do with your other data...

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you mean. Can you write a small example?

Comment: `self.client = client`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usual approach is , make client as datamember of class.

```
        self.client = ModbusClient(self.gatewayipaddress, port=self.port)
        self.client.connect()
        #some code here


    def closeconnection(self):
        self.readholdingregisters()
        self.client.close()
```

However if you want to access method through class `EnergyMeter.readholdingregisters()`

Then it should be declared as `staticmethod` or `classmethod` and this method should return client instance. [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12179271/python-classmethod-and-staticmethod-for-beginner)

Answer (score 0):

```
from pymodbus3.client.sync import ModbusTcpClient as ModbusClient

class EnergyMeter:
    def __init__(self, model, gatewayipaddress, port ,deviceid):
        self.model = model
        self.gatewayipaddress = gatewayipaddress
        self.port = port
        self.deviceid = deviceid
        self.client = ModbusClient(self.gatewayipaddress, port=self.port)
        self.client.connect()

    def readholdingregisters(self, startingregister, numberofregisters):
        if #some code here:
            #some other code here
            return concatResult
        else:
            return otherResult
```

Then, to close, you call `energy_meter.client.close()` for whatever `energy_meter` you want to close.

Comment: @KaloyanGeorgiev If it solved your issue, don't forget to check the "Accept Answer" check mark. Also, up-vote answers which you found helpful (including your accepted answer)