# Setting initial instance parameter using a class method

Tags: python, class-method

I have this code:

```
import random

class Player:

    def __init__(self):
        self.first_name = set_first_name()

    def set_first_name(self)
        List = open("player/first_names.txt").readlines()
        self.first_name = random.choice(List)
```

As you can see, I would like to set first name randomly from a text file. But I receive this error:

def set_first_name(self)                           ^
 SyntaxError: invalid syntax

I assume it is not possible to call a class method within the initialisation of a class instance. At least not the way I am doing it. Could sombody give me a quick hint? I suppose there is an easy fix to this.

Thanks

Comment: You missed `:` after `def set_first_name(self)`

Comment: Oh man. Thanks and sorry for the spam.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all as was allready mentioned - you missed `:` in define line.
Second: even if you fix that - you will get NameError because `set_first_name` is not in global scope. And for last - `set_first_name` doesn't returns anything, so you will get `first_name` as `None`.

Assuming that, right version of your code should look like:

```
import random

class Player:

    def __init__(self):
        self.first_name = self.set_first_name()

    @staticmethod
    def set_first_name():
        List = open("player/first_names.txt").readlines()
        return random.choice(List)
```

Comment: Thanks Yaroslav. I did your changes. After adding "self" as argument to set_first_name(), then it works perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your method is not a class method, you are simply missing the semi-colon from the end of your def line of the `set_first_name` method.

Comment: No problem. Please upvote and accept as answer if it helped.

Comment: Also, beware of using the term 'class method'. It refers to a specific way of calliing a method. Info is here https://stackoverflow.com/q/12179271/4047084 if you're interested.