# How to import datetime.today

Tags: python

I am new to Python, and try to import a `today` method from `datetime` module

The only workable way I can figure out is:

```
from datetime import datetime
datetime.today()
```

But, I would like to make `today` sit in the import statement, like `from os import getcwd` works,

I tried the following two ways, but neither works

```
from datetime import datettime.today
from datetime.datetime import today
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`today` is a class method of the `datetime` class:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> type(datetime.today)
<class 'builtin_function_or_method'>
```

Therefore, you can't import it on its own.

---

If you really want, you can alias it by assigning it to your own function:

```
from datetime import datetime
today = datetime.today
```

but you may not want to do that: it's not clear anymore that `today` is a `datetime` class method, and, given the name of the method, `today` can be read as a variable instead of as a function.

Comment: Thanks @evert. `datetime.today()` means calling `today` on a class `datetime`? If so, then `today` method looks like a static method  in Java, which can make ClassName.methodName call

Comment: @Tom Correct, it's (nearly) the same (I'm not familiar with static methods in Java). It can be seen as a constructor method that results in a `datetime` instance, hence it's part of the `datetime` class. Be aware, by the way, that Python has both class methods and static methods. The [answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12179271/meaning-of-classmethod-and-staticmethod-for-beginner) sheds some light on their differences.