# Calling python class method which has no argument

Tags: python, python-3.x, parameter-passing, self, class-method

I am new to python (coming from the c++ world) and was experimenting with class methods. I created a method without any argument (purposefully avoided `self` argument in this case). Then I tried to call it

```
class car:

    def car_method():
        print("Inside Car method")


obj = car_method()
obj.car_method()    <---- this creates error: TypeError: car_method() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given
```

I think this error is because, In Python, every class method, when called is always passed at least one argument which is that object's reference. am I correct?

Then to experiment further, I wrote

```
obj.car_method      <----- assuming I am not passing any argument to it
```

but the function printed nothing.

Then I tried to print the type of it using

`print(obj.car_method)`

which resulted in

`bound method car.car_method of <__main__.car object at 0x005D2290>`

Can anyone explain what is going on here? How do I 'call' the car_method? If there is no way to call the car_method, why does python let me define the method without any argument?

I am trying to get a good grasp on the basics here. Can I even call car_method as a class method? or it is just a method defined inside a class?

Comment: While writing last sentence `Can I even call car_method as a class method? or it is just a method defined inside class?`, I realised may be it is behaving differently, and after experimenting further, I realised, it is indeed a class method that can be used inside the class but not like `self.car_method()`. This will still give error. But calling it just like `car_method()` will work just fine provided you dont use it in any other class method!!!! it can be used as an class attribute!!

Answer (score 7):

In Python, all the methods of the class receive an instance of the class object implicitly as the first argument.

It's general practice in Python to name the first argument in class methods as `self` it's like `this` in C and Java-like languages. The only difference, it's not a reserved keyword and you can name it anything. Though it's a general convention to use `self` as it is more readable to Python programmers and Python documentation, IDE parsers. [Read the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#random-remarks).

You can access class methods and variables across methods of the class using self. A very simple example showing the use case of self:

```
In [37]: class car:
    ...:     def __init__(self):
    ...:         self.car_name = 'Jaguar'
    ...:
    ...:     def car_method(self):
    ...:         print("I can access " + self.car_name + " because I have
    ...: self")
    ...:         print("Inside Car method")
    ...:
    ...:     def another_method(self):
    ...:         # this calls car_method
    ...:         self.car_method()
    ...:

In [38]: c = car()

In [39]: c.another_method()
I can access Jaguar because I have self
Inside Car method
```

If you want a [classmethod](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/classmethod). You can define a class method in Python as:

```
class car:

    @classmethod
    def car_method(cls):
        print("Inside Car method")
```

The little thing `@classmethod` on top of the `car_method` method is called [decorator](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=decorator%20python&oq=decorator%20python&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60l3j0l2.2228j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) in Python. But even in class methods, the class instance is passed as an argument in car_method.

If you want to call your method `car_method` without an argument and do not need to access class/instance variables(these are called static methods). You can define your method as a static method with a `@staticmethod` decorator.

```
class car:

    @staticmethod
    def car_method():
        print("Inside Car method")
```

Here no `self` is passed as argument and you can call car_method as `car().car_method()`

**Why Python allow car_method to be created even when self is passed as an argument?**

It's because Python is not statically typed like C. It's a dynamic language. Unlike statically-typed languages, all the type, function argument, etc checking happens at runtime in Python

To know more about @classmethod and @staticmethod decorator, [read about @classmethod and @staticmethod in this awesome SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12179271/meaning-of-classmethod-and-staticmethod-for-beginner)

Comment: thanks for responding, whay you mentioned are `classmethod` and `staticmethod`, but I wanted to know what is a method inside a class that is not either of them? how does it behave, its benifits/uses and how do I call it? I added a comment after I posted the post, so please comment on that as well. I am curious to know this!

Comment: @legameeternoforall Added an example in the answer. I suggest you read the doc I attached. It gives a very good start about OOP in Python.

Comment: @legameeternoforall Feel free to [accept my answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if you feel it was useful to you. :-)

Answer (score 1):

in python a method of class is defined by like this:

```py
class MyObj(object):

    def my_method(self):
        pass
```

always at least one first argument which is the instance itself.

Answer (score 0):

To access `ca_method(`) inside `car` class, you just need to create an instance of the `car` class and then use the method.
For example:

```
class car:

    def car_method():
       print("Inside Car method")

a = car()
a.car_method()
```

or just simply:

```
class car:
    
    def car_method():
           print("Inside Car method")
    
car().car_method()
```

Answer (score 0):

**TESTED** Add "self" argument.

```
class car:
      def car_method(self):
         print("Inside Car Method") 
obj=car() 
obj.car_method()
```

I had the same challenge but adding the self resolved it.

Answer (score 0):

self is a instance of class ion python. you will get error if you avoid self as argument. if you don't have any arguments to pass to the method, you have three ways to overcome.

1 set self as None, if you don't have any arguments to pass

```
class car:
def car_method(self=None):
    print("test text")
obj = car
obj.car_method()
```

2 You can define your method as a static method with a @staticmethod
decorator

```
class car:
@staticmethod
def car_method():
    print("Inside Car method")

obj = car
obj.car_method()
```

3 pass the instance of the object by putting a bracket at the end of object call

```
class car:
def car_method(self):
    print("test text")

obj = car()
obj.car_method()
```