# usecase @classmethod and @staticmethod

Tags: python-3.x

I almost browsed for use cases, but couldn't find appropriate answers.

I know the difference between two: Please correct me if i'm wrong.
@classmethod
Takes cls as 1st argument and It can be called by both classname and instance)
@staticmethod
Doesn't take self as 1st argument.It can be called by both classname and instance). It acts as utility to class.

But, please anybody explain me when to use which method, where all it can be applied.

Advance Thanks,

Comment: a simple search revealed this article: http://stackabuse.com/pythons-classmethod-and-staticmethod-explained/

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12179271/meaning-of-classmethod-and-staticmethod-for-beginner

Comment: Thanks Edwin,  stackoverflow.com/questions/12179271/ this explains it more clearly.