# JavaScript error Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Tags: javascript, html, django

I am making a website using HTML5 Javascript and Django 1.8 , Python 3.5 and I am getting the following error

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

```js
class User {
  constructor(nothing) {
    //doNothing
  }

  function myFunction(p1, p2) {
    return p1 * p2; // The function returns the product of p1 and p2
  }


  function afunc() {
    var mydata = "kk";

    return (mydata);
  }
}
var abc = new User();
var kk = abc.myFunction(1, 2);
console.log(kk);
```

**EDIT**

Is there any debugger for Javascript in Pycharm latest version(2018) like we have a debugger for Java in netbeans we can add breakpoints see values of variables etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

remove the `function` from the `class` methods. `class` methods don`t use function declarations as its methods.

```js
class User {
    constructor(nothing){
        //doNothing
    }
    myFunction(p1, p2) {
        return p1 * p2;
    }

    afunc() {
        var mydata="kk";

        return (mydata);
    }
}
var abc=new User();
var kk=abc.myFunction(1,2);
console.log(kk);
```

Comment: Question edited if u answer it I will accept your anser

Comment: 1) [Pycharm Professional - JS debugging](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/debugging-javascript-in-chrome.html)
2) I think you could also use a [@classmethod](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12179752/9155312) decorator.

Comment: Also I would like to mention that you should limit your questions to the scope of the original question. If zabusa's answer did resolve your question please accept.

Comment: @dddar change to `vscode` dont use `pycharm` for javascript.dont mess python with javascript