# Python Class Method Line Not Running

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, oop, methods

An experienced VBA programmer here, that is starting the delve into Python OOP. I fear it is so simple, that I am having issues finding an answer without asking for help.

I have written the following code:

```
#Import packages
import openpyxl as xl
import os

class DataExtract:

#Initialize the class
def __init__(self,wb):
    self.wb = wb

#Set class method to return sheet for named range
@classmethod
def rng_sht(cls,dest):
    for title, coord in dest:
        return(title)

#Set class method to return cell for named range
@classmethod
def rng_coord(cls,dest):
    for title, coord in dest:
        return(coord)

#Set class method to retun value of named range
@classmethod
def rng_val(cls,rng):

    #Define destinations
    dest = wb.get_named_range(rng).destinations

    #Retrieve sheet
    sht = DataExtract.rng_sht(dest)
    coord  = DataExtract.rng_coord(dest)

    #Return value       
    return()


#Define workbook
wb = 'Test_WB'

#Initiate class
wb_cur = DataExtract(wb)

#Find temp for current sheet
Temp = wb_cur.rng_val('Temp')
```

I'm aware that my indentation is incorrect.

The issue that I am having is that when I call the rng_val class method, it is only returning the current value for the first method I call within (in this case, the "sht"). When I inactivate the "sht" line, the "coord" line functions correctly.

I suspect the issue is likely due to how I am calling class methods or how I have structured the class, but I am not sure.

### Update

I have updated the code with feedback from all of you, with my script below. I am still having errors with exiting the loop in the rng_val class, which Max suggested `yield` to resolve. I attempted to fix to no avail.

```
#Import packages
import openpyxl as xl
import os

class DataExtract:

    #Initialize the class
    def __init__(self,wb):
        self.wb = wb

    #Set class method to return sheet for named range
    @classmethod
    def rng_sht(cls,dest):
        for title, coord in dest:
            return title

    #Set class method to return cell for named range
    @classmethod
    def rng_coord(cls,dest):
        for title, coord in dest:
            return coord

    #Set class method to retun value of named range
    @classmethod
    def rng_val(cls,wb,rng):

        #Define destinations
        dest = wb.get_named_range(rng).destinations

        #Retrieve sheet
        sht = cls.rng_sht(dest)
        coord  = cls.rng_coord(dest)

        print(sht)
        print(coord)

        #Return value       
        return 1


path = 'C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\Python\\PracFiles\\'

#Loop through workbooks in a given folder
for i in os.listdir(path):

    #Define workbook
    wb = xl.load_workbook(path + i,data_only=True)

    #Find temp for current sheet
    Temp = DataExtract.rng_val(wb,'Temp')
```

Comment: If you are aware - why not fix it?

Comment: Issue with the indentation when copying over. Given the simplicity of the code, I don't suspect anyone will have any issues following.

Comment: But if we try to reproduce your problem then we have to correct the indentation, just because you can't be bothered.

Comment: Well the next python newbie finding this question with your problem which seems to be his as well will be confused - maybe revisit [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and  [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), Python needs indentation and not having it introduces more errors in your code that we have to fix.

Comment: in `rng_val` you have a `return` within a loop, wich causes the loop to exit during the first iteration. You may want to have a look at the `yield` keyword.

Comment: Code updated. 
Thanks Max, I'll try now. 
Cheers

Comment: Mabye also have a look at [meaning-of-classmethod-and-staticmethod-for-beginner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12179271/meaning-of-classmethod-and-staticmethod-for-beginner) and fix the missing `self.`/`cls.` in your classes method. Your classmethods kindof look as if they should be instancemethods instead.

Comment: Hi Max, 
I tried using the  yield keywork in my loops, then converted the object to a string using the .join method and I am having the same issue. Why would a loop in the different class method exit the initiate class method calling it?

Comment: I've wrapped my head around the 'yield' keyword a bit more now. Basically, when I call the "dest" object once, it erases.

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues I can see that may have to do with your inexperience with Python OO.

1. The empty `return` statements *cannot* have parenthesis after them. That would cause the function to return an empty tuple instead of nothing.
2. If you plan on having your function return a value, place the value (or variable) immediately after the return statement like this: `return coord`. `return` on its own will just exit the function.
3. The first parameter in any class method contains the instance of that class when called via an object. You called it `self` in the constructor and `cls` in the other methods. They are the same thing. You haven't been using it in your code in places it looks like it should be. See below:

   ```
   sht = DataExtract.rng_sht(dest)
   coord  = DataExtract.rng_coord(dest)
   ```

That would call the function `rng_sht` *statically* passing `dest` as an instance of `DataExtract` which I'm near certain isn't intended. What you should do instead is use `cls.rng_sht(dest)` to references the object instance. Also, you cannot access class fields by just referencing them by themselves, like `wb.get_named_range(rng)` where `wb` is a field in `DataExtract`. Instead reference it via `cls` like `cls.wb.get_named_range(rng)`

Comment: `return(1)` does not return a tuple - it returns a int. `return 1,` returns a tuple, as does `return(1,)`

Comment: `return()` and `return(1,)` both return tuples.