# What is the difference between __main__ and class '__main__?

Tags: python

I am learning about classmethod.
I have looked at this example

```
class A(object):
    def foo(self,x):
        print (self,x)

    @classmethod
    def class_foo(cls,x):
        print(cls,x)

    @staticmethod
    def static_foo(x):
        print (x)   

a=A()
a.foo('pic')
a.class_foo('pic')
```

This is output

```
<__main__.A object at 0x7f413121c080> pic
<class '__main__.A'> pic
```

What is the practical meaning of this?Implementation?

Comment: The first is the default string representation of an object (whose type is `__main__.A`). The second is the default string representation of the class `__main__.A`.

Comment: `"__main__"` is the name of the current module in the repl or in a script. If you imported the class from a file called `foobar.py`, the class would be represented as `foobar.A` instead of `__main__.A`. Pretty useful for debugging to know where the class was defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implementation-wise, a `classmethod` takes the first obligatory `cls` argument, which is not the case for a `staticmethod`.

The practical meaning is that you can call a `classmethod` without having to create a class object first. In code this is perfectly valid:

```
A.class_foo('pic')
```

You can read more about this subject on this excellent [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12179271/meaning-of-classmethod-and-staticmethod-for-beginner) post.

Comment: The staticmethod is not really relevant for the question, though.

Comment: @Simke used a `staticmethod` in his code, that's why I thought it might be helpful to include this info too.

Comment: OP defined it, but it's never called. And the question is about `__main__` in the output of the methods `foo` and `foo_class`