# NameError in python but everything is defined (and spelt correctly)

Tags: python, function, class

I've just started to use classes and i decided to create a quick login program.
the program should setup a user and let them login but i'm getting a NameError whenever I run the program I've checked the spelling and everything seems to be correct. Any help would be appreciated

```
 class User(object):

    def __init__(self, name1, name2 , age , username, passw):
        self.name1 = name1
        self.name2 = name2
        self.age = age
        self.username = username
        self.passw = passw

    def user_setup(self):
        try:
            name1 = str(input("Please enter your first name : "))
            try:
                name2 = str(input("Please enter your last name : "))
                try:
                    age = int(input("Please enter your age in years"))
                except ValueError:
                    print("Thats not allowed")
            except ValueError:
                    print("Thats not allowed")
        except ValueError:
                    print("Thats not allowed")
        self.username = self.name1[0:3] + str(self.age)
        return self.username


    def login(self):
        for i in range(4):
            loginUsername = input("Please enter your username : ")
            if loginUsername == self.username:
                loginPassword = input("Please enter your password : ")
                if loginPassword == self.passw:
                    print("You have loggged in as " + self.username)
                else:
                    print("invalid")
            else:
                print("invalid")
        print("You have entered your username or password incorrectly too many times")
        quit()

def main():

    menu = int(input("1.new user\n2.login\n-"))
    if menu == 1:
        user_setup()
        login()
    elif menu == 2:
        login()
        print("test")



main()
```

THE ERROR I GET WHEN I RUN THE PROGRAM:

```
1.new user
2.login
-1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\colin\Desktop\Python programs\Password generator.py", line 58, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\colin\Desktop\Python programs\Password generator.py", line 50, in main
    user_setup()
NameError: name 'user_setup' is not defined
```

Comment: You will need to create a `User()` object before you use `user_setup()`

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

Change `user_setup()` to `User.user_setup()` in `main()`, since `user_setup()` is a method of the `User` class, python won't find it as a normal function.

You would also want to change `login()` to `User.login()`

However, classes are rather used in another way, for example a new user would more often be made by combining your `user_setup()` and `__init__()` and then creating a user this way:

```
user1 = User(...)
```

Comment: it won't work as it is an unbound method it must be called with User instance

Comment: Indeed, I changed my answer a bit, but FHTMitchells answer is better

Answer (score 0):

`user_setup` is a method on the class so you will need to instantiate that first before you can use it:

```
user = User(name1='foo', name2='bar', age=21, username='foobar', password='secret')
user.user_setup()
```

Answer (score 0):

`user_setup()` is a method of `User`. You need to create a `User` instance and then call the method like so

```
user = User(name1, name2, age, username, passw)
user.user_setup()
```

If you want to call it without instantiating first, make `user_setup` a [classmethod](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12179271/meaning-of-classmethod-and-staticmethod-for-beginner) and use like so:

```
User.user_setup()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a User instance, then call the appropriate method. Also, in your `__init__` you need to give default value for argument name etc.