# Unable to create Pub/Sub Publisher Client using .json key file

Tags: python-3.x, google-api, google-cloud-pubsub

I'm unable to create Pub/Sub Publisher Client using .json file (instead using implicit Application Default / GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS env var). Is something wrong I'm doing or does Pub/Sub has some nuances ? in which case why so...?

Most Google Client Libraries allow this, for ex BigQuery

```
client = bigquery.Client.from_service_account_json(json_credentials_path = ‘PATH/service_account.json')
```

Digging through [PubSub Client Library code](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-python/blob/4944e023d439cb628513f228c1593cd7a59bbdb9/pubsub/google/cloud/pubsub_v1/gapic/publisher_client.py#L62), I tried to do same with Pub/Sub Client Library:

```
from google.cloud.pubsub_v1.gapic.publisher_client import PublisherClient
publisher = PublisherClient.from_service_account_file(filename='PATH/service_account.json')
```

And get the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 1, in
>
> File “/[VIRT_ENV_PATH]/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/cloud/pubsub_v1/gapic/publisher_client.py", line 78, in from_service_account_file return cls(*args, **kwargs)
>
> File "/[VIRT_ENV_PATH]/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/cloud/pubsub_v1/gapic/publisher_client.py", line 167, in **init**   self.iam_policy_stub = (iam_policy_pb2.IAMPolicyStub(channel))
>
> File
>   "/[VIRT_ENV_PATH]/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/iam/v1/iam_policy_pb2.py", line 344, in **init** self.SetIamPolicy = channel.unary_unary( AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'unary_unary'

If I want to use key .json file, I could only make it work using workaround,

```
cred = `service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(filename = 'PATH/service_account.json')
publisher = pubsub_v1.PublisherClient(credentials = cred)
```

Thanks in advance for giving me.

Comment: It looks like this function ask for some cls object ( *def from_service_account_file(cls, filename, *args, **kwargs):* ). But, in any case, inside the function it does exactly what you do. So, your workaround could be a good solution. Did you found what CLS stands for?

Comment: Hi Temu, it's a @classmethod, an thats why cls as first argument: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12179271/meaning-of-classmethod-and-staticmethod-for-beginner

Comment: Wow, you are totally right, I missed it. Long day. Sorry for the oversight!

Answer (score 4):

As far as I can see, we can do this in three different ways:

If you want to specify directly the key.json file instead of [setting the environment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS as specified in docs...](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production) which would be this:

```
import os
import google.cloud.pubsub_v1 as pub 
os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS']='.path/auth.json'
publisher = pub.PublisherClient()
```

Furthermore, you can use your workaround:

```
import google.cloud.pubsub_v1 as pub 
from google.cloud.pubsub_v1.gapic.publisher_client import PublisherClient 
cred = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(filename = './auth.json') #or just from_service_account_file('./auth.json')
publisher = pub.PublisherClient(credentials = cred)
```

But regarding the third way...

```
from google.cloud.pubsub_v1.gapic.publisher_client import PublisherClient #VERSION 1
publisher = PublisherClient.from_service_account_file('./auth.json')
#which raises the same error than:
#publisher = PublisherClient('./auth.json')
```

... a [GitHub issue should be opened](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-python/issues) since it is related with providing [none channel in the constructor, line 101](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-python/blob/4944e023d439cb628513f228c1593cd7a59bbdb9/pubsub/google/cloud/pubsub_v1/gapic/publisher_client.py#L101) and this is not behavior expected. ***You were doing it right on the first time.***