# python3 : avoid creation of duplicate key in dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

Here's my example code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

LIST_OF_UNITS = {}

class Unit():
    def __init__(self,name, value):
       self.name = name
       self.value = value

def create_new_unit(name, value):
    return Unit(name, value)

def add_new_unit(d, name, value):
    d[name] = Unit(name, value)
    return d

unit = create_new_unit('reactor1', 1)
LIST_OF_UNITS[unit.name] = unit

unit = create_new_unit('reactor2', 2)
LIST_OF_UNITS[unit.name] = unit

LIST_OF_UNITS = add_new_unit(LIST_OF_UNITS, 'reactor3', 3)

print(LIST_OF_UNITS)

LIST_OF_UNITS = add_new_unit(LIST_OF_UNITS, 'reactor3', 4)

print(LIST_OF_UNITS)
```

As you can see I have two ways of adding objects to the dictionary. Not yet sure which is the better. One may be more flexible for solving my problem. So, I've included them both.

I want to build a list of reactors and their properties.

For each reactor I create an object that will eventually contain the properties of that reactor (like it's volume, operation start and end times,etc.)

I'd like to prevent the (duplicate) creation of a unit. In the example the creation of 'reactor3' with value **4** should be avoided.

What would be the best way to do that. Inside the class, using one of the methods or somehow else?

Your insights are greatly appreciated.

Comment: You could add a simple check in the function like this: `if not name in d:`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change your code around some, you can store all created `Unit`s as classvariable inside `Unit`. The factory-methods shoult be classmethods and will auto-add/create your instances to it.

```
class Unit():
    UNITS = {} # shared btw. instances

    def __init__(self, name, value):
        self.name = name 
        self.value = value

    # nicer output
    def __repr__(self): return "{} - {}".format(self.name, self.value)    
    def __str__(self):  return repr(self) 

# this should be a classmethod instead, depending on your usage you might want to
# raise Errors instead of returning existing instances
def create_new_unit(name, value):
    # create if needed, else return the one already in
    # does not alter Unit.value if present
    u = Unit.UNITS.setdefault(name, Unit(name,value))
    if u.value != value:
        raise ValueError("Unit '{}' exists with different value".format(name))
    else:
        return u

# this should be a classmethod instead, depending on your usage you might want to
# raise Errors instead of returning existing instances    def add_new_unit(name, value):
    # create new unit or alter an existing Unit's value
    # you should rename the method accordingly
    u = Unit.UNITS.setdefault(name, Unit(name,value)) 
    u.value = value  # change it if called again 
    return Unit.UNITS

unit1 = create_new_unit('reactor1', 1) 

unit2 = create_new_unit('reactor2', 2) 

all_units = add_new_unit('reactor3', 3)

for u in Unit.UNITS:
    print(id(Unit.UNITS[u]),Unit.UNITS[u]) 

all_units = add_new_unit('reactor3', 4)

for u in Unit.UNITS:
    print(id(Unit.UNITS[u]),Unit.UNITS[u])
```

Output:

```
140125186245968 reactor1 - 1
140125186246024 reactor2 - 2
140125186246080 reactor3 - 3

140125186245968 reactor1 - 1
140125186246024 reactor2 - 2
140125186246080 reactor3 - 4 # changed by add_new_unit


# if create_new_unit(..) same named unit again with different value:
# ValueError: Unit 'reactor2' exists with different value
```

---

Personally I would advice against creating multiple ways to instantiate new ones. And I would probably put the "factory methods" as @classmethods and not inside the normal program. That way all the *housekeeping* of `Unit`s is done by the 
`Unit` class itself, and you can centralize the logic where it belongs instead of having to add created Units inside your main program.

Suggested read for `@classmethod`: [Meaning of @classmethod and @staticmethod for beginner?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12179271/meaning-of-classmethod-and-staticmethod-for-beginner)

Answer (score 1):

Just make check if the item is already in the keys of the dictionary. Insert only if not already there.

```
def add_new_unit(d, name, value):
    if(name in d.keys()):
        print("The reactor information for {name} already recorded!".format(name = name))
        return d
    d[name] = Unit(name, value)
    return d
```

Comment: `if name in d:` is sufficient. No `.keys()` needed.

Comment: @schwobaseggl, yes, indeed. Any specific reason as to why not use it, though?

Comment: It feels more pythonic (also omitting the java-style parentheses). In Python2, `keys()` also returns a list and thus significantly worsens the membership check performance wise. While that has been remedied in Python3, `name in d` is still the more generally applicable.

Answer (score 0):

If you add an entry with the same key to the dictionary, the item will be overwritten so you will lose 1 of the entries.

If you want to avoid that, you can check if the name is already in the key values of the dictionary.

How about this?

```
if name in LIST_OF_UNITS.keys():
   # raise an error
else:
   pass
```

Comment: No need for `keys()`. `x in dct` checks whether a key `x` is in `dct`.

Comment: Yes this works.  I just thought adding keys() would be more helpful for a beginner to understand if the key already exists, but x in dct is more simple.