# unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'DeferredAttribute' and 'str'

Tags: python, django

I am trying to save a model via the admin but i keep getting this error

```
unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'DeferredAttribute' and 'str'".
```

I want to return a string representation for the model.

this is what i have tried:

```
def __str__(self):
    return str(self.album_name + "" + self.artist)
```

My model:

```
class Album(models.Model):
    album_name = models.CharField(max_length=250,)
    album_logo = models.FilePathField(path='music/static/music/song_logo', 
    null=True, blank=True, recursive=True)
    artist = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    primaryid = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, null=False)

    @classmethod
    def __str__(self):
        return self.album_name + " " + self.artist
```

I want to get something like 'hilltop' for example

Answer (score 2):

`__str__` shouldn't be a `classmethod`, removing that decorator will resolve your issue.

You are passing the class (`Album`) to the `__str__` method as `self` instead of an instance. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12179271/meaning-of-classmethod-and-staticmethod-for-beginner) for details.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove `@classmethod` decorator from your model because it shouldn't be.

Furthermore, `self.artist` is  `CharField` if you try to concatenate it by using below syntax in your `models.py` 's `__str__()` method.

```
@classmethod
    def __str__(self):
        return "{0} {1}".format(self.album_name,self.artist)
```