# How can i take python self class attributes in class's method?

Tags: python, class, methods, attributes

I started with Python's classes and I want to do something like that:

```
class First:
    def __init__(self):
        self.value = 1

    @classmethod
    def func(cls):
        print(self.value)


second = First()
second.func()
```

But i can't access `self.value` of the class. Can anybody help me?

Comment: when using `classmethod`, you want to pass `cls` not `self`. But class methods cannot and should not depend on the state of the instance. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12179271/meaning-of-classmethod-and-staticmethod-for-beginner

Comment: `@classmethod`s take `cls`, which is the class. Remove the decorator if you want to take `self` which is the object instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC then your class should look like the following:

```
class First:
    value = 1

    @classmethod
    def func(cls):
        print(cls.value)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to create a function in your class and use self parameters just do that :

```
class First:
    def __init__(self):
        self.value = 1

    def func(self):
        print(self.value)


second = First()
second.func()
```

Answer (score 0):

Is `@classmothod` necessary?
If it is eliminated, the class works well.

```
class First:
    def __init__(self):
        self.value = 1

    def func(self):
        print(self.value)

second = First()
second.func()
```