# passing data from one class method to another class method

Tags: python, class

I am learning Python and classes and i encountered a challenge that i need help with.

When I try to pass data from one class method to another class method i run into an error that tells me it misses a positional argument

example:

```
class Student:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def pass_to_dl(self):
       DataLayer.Datalayer.create_dict_entry(self.name)



class Datalayer:
   def __init__(self):
        self.dict = {}

   def create_dict_entry(self, name):
       new_name = {"name":name}
       self.dict.update(new_name)


new_student = Student("some_name")
```

The error I get is:

```
TypeError: create_new_student() missing 1 required positional argument:
```

i assume it is because create_dict_entry expects two arguments and I am sending only one

now i can overcome this if i do two things

1. make the create_dict_entry in DataLayer static
2. move the dict outside of the DataLayer class
   but truthfully that does not seem like the right approach to me i think

i would love to hear your view on this matter

thnx

ps. i dont want student to inherit from DataLayer as i consider DataLayer a non related class that just holds data that i acquire form classes such as Student, Teacher etc

Comment: please make your code valid. E.g. there should be `:` after `class Student`

Comment: The thing you call a 'class method' is just a 'method'. There is such thing as 'class method', you can read about it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12179271/meaning-of-classmethod-and-staticmethod-for-beginner

Answer (score 0):

Not sure it's the way you want to go, but if I understand correctly what you're trying to do, I think you want to use **inheritance**.

```py
class Datalayer:
    def __init__(self):
        self.dict = {}

    def create_dict_entry(self, name):
        new_name = {"name":name}
        self.dict[self.name] = new_name

class Student(Datalayer):
    def __init__(self, name):
        super().__init__()
        self.name = name

    def pass_to_dl(self):
        self.create_dict_entry(self.name)
```

So in this example, `Student` is your "child class" (that's why you pass `Datalayer` as its argument). In your `__init__`, you want to call `super(Student, self).__init__()` (or just `super().__init__()` to instantiate your "parent class", `Datalayer` so you can access trigger its `__init__` function.

You may want to read some other examples to understand it properly (https://realpython.com/python-super/).

Comment: thnx, i am not sure why, but i wanted to avoid making Student a child class of Datalayer. in my mind datalayer is a datastorage class that resides in paralel.

Comment: Then maybe a simple side function is enough ?

To me, it looks kind of weird to have several classes that you need to instantiate : it seems simpler, and I guess more "pythonic" to use inheritance.

Comment: i understand your comment, but i am not trying to create an instance in the Datalayer, i just want to call a method with DataLayer that stores data within the class itself. Makes sense, or am i going in the wrong direction?

Comment: You need to instantiate your class if you want to use the dict you have as one of its property (self.dict in the Datalayer class).