# Use of self when calling functions within a class

Tags: python

I'm new to programming and can't quite grasp the formalism of classes. I have a file plots.py consisting of a class of functions:

```
import numpy as np

class SHO1D:
    def prob(T, x, N):
        i = x+1
        product = 1
        while i <= N:
            product *= (1 - np.exp(-1/T)**i)
            i += 1
        return np.exp(-1/T)**x * product

    def bec(T, N):
        n_0 = 0.
        for x in range(N + 1):
            n_0 += SHO1D.prob(T, x, N) * x
        return n_0
```

I'm successfully importing this class in another file as follows:

```
from plots import SHO1D

N = 100
temps = np.logspace(1,1.45,num=300)
plt.plot(temps, SHO1D.bec(temps, N))
```

However, I've read in a number of posts that, when calling functions within a class, I shouldn't prefix my functions with their class name as I did above. Rather, I should make use of `self`. I've not been able to modify my program above to make use of this feature without redefining my function `bec` to include a third argument "self" in addition to "T" and "N", which I would like to avoid because I want to be able to plot those functions. As such, I would appreciate an explanation as to how this feature should be implemented in my case.

Comment: This series of videos about classes and objects helped me out a lot when I was confused about the same thing, check it out: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8yjkWGRlUmY

Comment: Your class shouldn't be a class if you aren't using internal state, it should just be a module with functions.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga unless the rest of his/her file was huge and she/he just wanted to group the functions in a meaningful way. Assuming all of his/her functions are magically related to the module/file.

Comment: I wanted to use classes as a way to categorize different sets of functions, e.g. I would like to have a number of classes each with a function "prob" or "bec" (that describe the same thing but under different conditions). I think this could save me from possible confusion later on if I were to instead assign a unique name to each individual function, especially if I'd like to reuse some functions from other classes in the file. Perhaps there is a better way to do this than with the use of classes.

Comment: @theX that's not a good reason to use a class. You can just split your modules up.

Comment: @Daphne that is fundamentally not what a class is for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, please follow [Python code style guide (aka PEP8)](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), it's necessary for understanding your code in future.

About your implementation:

By default, Python uses `self` as the first argument for all functions in a class (when functions are not decorated with `@classmethod` or `@staticmethod`, [about decorators](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0318/), [classmethod and staticmethod for beginners](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12179271/meaning-of-classmethod-and-staticmethod-for-beginner)).

So in your case, in all functions, `T` it's an object of your class. But for this statement, you need to create a class instance ([all about classes](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html)).

You have a few ways to resolve a problem:

1. Create an instance of the class and use `self`.

For example:

```py
class SHO1D:
    def __init__(self, T):
        self.T = T

    def prob(self, x, N):
        i = x+1
        product = 1
        while i <= N:
            product *= (1 - np.exp(-1/self.T)**i)
            i += 1
        return np.exp(-1/self.T)**x * product

    def bec(self, N):
        n_0 = 0.
        for x in range(N + 1):
            n_0 += self.prob(x, N) * x
        return n_0
```

And:

```py
from plots import SHO1D

N = 100
temps = np.logspace(1,1.45,num=300)
sho1d_temps = SHO1D(temps)
plt.plot(temps, sho1d_temps.bec(N))
```

2. Decorate methods using `@classmethod`:

```py
class SHO1D:
    @classmethod
    def prob(cls, T, x, N):
        i = x+1
        product = 1
        while i <= N:
            product *= (1 - np.exp(-1/T)**i)
            i += 1
        return np.exp(-1/T)**x * product

    @classmethod
    def bec(cls, T, N):
        n_0 = 0.
        for x in range(N + 1):
            n_0 += cls.prob(T, x, N) * x
        return n_0
```

The second part does not need to be changed.

Answer (score 0):

`self` is used a lot when using classes. To use it, put it as the first parameter in your function (which is inside the class). When calling the function (`class().function()`), the `self` parameter would be autofilled by Python, so you only need to fill in the original parameters.
Local variables are variables defined inside a function that can't be reached after the function is called (unless the variable is returned). `self` is a property of the class. If it's changed by a function inside the same class, it is saved. Think of it as a dictionary passed in as an argument: `self.property`

You should find variables inside the functions that you would like to save and be able to use in other functions (in the same class).

I also suggest you put some comments in your code, because right now I'm not getting anything out of your code (If I did, I might be able to suggest what to turn into properties of the `self`).

```
class SHO1D():
    def prob(self, T, x, N):
        i = x+1
        product = 1
        while i <= N:
            product *= (1 - np.exp(-1/T)**i)
            i += 1
        return np.exp(-1/T)**x * product

    def bec(self, T, N):
        n_0 = 0
        for x in range(N + 1):
            n_0 += self.prob(T, x, N) * x
        return n_0
```