# What is the difference between @classmethod decorator method and the normal method?

Tags: python

Example 1:

```
class names:   
    def myname(self):       
        return 'my name is python'  
word = names().myname()
print(word)
```

Result:

```
my name is python
```

Example 2:

```
class names:   
    @classmethod
    def myname(cls):
        cls.justaname = 'my name is python'
        return cls.justaname
word = names().myname()
print(word)
```

Result:

```
my name is python
```

1 - What is the difference between the two methods ?

2 - What changes did '@classmethod' make to the second example ?

3 - I can make the second example work without '@classmethod' decorator so what is the point of adding it is it useless ?

Comment: Try `names.myname()` on both examples.

Comment: [What is the purpose of @classmethod in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64496373/2745495)

Comment: everything works perfectly but what is the difference ? both programs give the same result so can you tell me what is the difference between using '@classmethod' and without using '@classmethod' ?

Comment: even if i don't use '@classmethod' python knows that this function doesn't belong to any instance i don't see any difference do you see any difference ?

Comment: Like I said (and what's explained in the links to the other questions), `names.myname()` (notice no `()` on `names`, not creating an instance of `names`) will _only_ work on Example 2. That's the difference.