# Use a class variable in a class method

Tags: python

After I ran the code below, I got `NameError: name 'result' is not defined`. I tried to use class variable in a class method. Why does it give me an error?

```
class Test():
    def __init__(self):
        self.a=self.test1()
        self.result = Test.test2()+Test.test3()
    def test1(self):
        a=100
        return a

    result = Test.test3()+100
    @classmethod
    def test2(cls):
        b=200
        return b

    @staticmethod
    def test3():
        print("Testing3 is calling ")
        c=500+Test.result
        return c
```

Error:

```
result = Test.test3()+100
  File "<ipython-input-29-29d4025016c1>", line 18, in test3
    c=500+result
  NameError: name 'result' is not defined
```

Comment: I believe you need it to be self.result = Test.test3()+100

Comment: self.result = Test.test3()+100 will not work.  the problem comes from c=500+Test.result
        return c

Comment: `Test.result` is declared in the line `result = Test.test3()+100`, so how can it be declared at the time `Test.test3()` is being called? There is a circular reference.

Comment: I'd refer to this thread on how to properly use classmethod and staticmethod: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12179271/meaning-of-classmethod-and-staticmethod-for-beginner

However beyond that, @kaya3 is right - you have other syntax issues here like the test.test3()+100 line

Comment: In your own words, where you have `result = Test.test3()+100`, what do you expect that to do, and *when*? Where you have `c=500+Test.result`, do you see how that depends on `result = Test.test3()+100` having already occurred? Could it have already occurred?

Comment: Aside from that, I can't understand what *problem you are trying to solve* with code like this.

Comment: I think   result = Test.test3()+100  is defined result. why the result shows result is not defined in   c=500+Test.result

Answer (score 1):

At the time the line of code in question is evaluated, `result` is not a class variable.  It's been defined as an instance variable here:

```
    def __init__(self):
        self.a=self.test1()
        self.result = Test.test2()+Test.test3()
```

but the line of code that defines `Test.result` as a class variable:

```
    result = Test.test3()+100
```

has not yet finished executing at the time that it calls `test3()`, which itself has a dependency on `Test.result`.