# How to call a method of a class in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-class

With below code I am trying to find the oldest of the 3 cats. When I try to call the method 'cat_age' of class 'Cat' in the print statement it gives the below error:

**NameError: name 'cat_age' is not defined**

Below is the code:

```
class Cat:
  def __init__(self, name, age):
    self.name=name
    self.age=age
  def cat_age(self, *args):
    return max(args)


cat1=Cat('Pinky', 10)
cat2=Cat('Tinky', 11)
cat3=Cat('Sinky', 13)



print(f'The oldest cat is {cat_age(cat1.age, cat2.age, cat3.age)} years old')
```

Please help me understand what is going on.

Comment: Why do you need `cat_age`? It is just a wrapper over `max`?

Comment: "When I try to call the method 'cat_age' of class 'Cat'" - no, you call just a function `cat_age`. There's no mention of `Cat` anywhere nearby.

Comment: An instance method is called on an ***instance***. i.e. `cat1.some_method()`. But you are calling a method as if it was a function in the global scope. Anyway `cat_age` doesn't make sense as an instance method. ***Maybe*** it could be a `@classmethod` receiving an arbitrary number of instances of its class

Comment: Could be: `print(
    f'The oldest cat is {cat1.cat_age(cat1.age, cat2.age, cat3.age)} years old'
)`

Answer (score 2):

When you define a function inside a class, that defines an ***instance*** method. These are functions that are called on a ***specific*** instance of the class and get it (the instance) as an argument. You call those as `instance.method()`.

So when you `def cat_age(self, *args):` inside the class - this is an instance method. But then you call it as `cat_age(...)` and such name does not exist in the global scope.

To be frank, it doesn't make much sense to define such method as it is just a wrapper on the `max` built-in function and it is a lot more readable to just use.... `max`.

But if you really wanted, you could define a [`@staticmethod`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12179271/meaning-of-classmethod-and-staticmethod-for-beginner) that takes an arbitrary number of instances:

```py
class Cat:
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age

    @staticmethod
    def max_age(*args):
        return max(arg.age for arg in args)

cat1 = Cat('Pinky', 10)
cat2 = Cat('Tinky', 11)
cat3 = Cat('Sinky', 13)

print(f'The oldest cat is {Cat.max_age(cat1, cat2, cat3)} years old')
```

Will print:

```
The oldest cat is 13 years old
```