# Subclass function gets called instead of the main class function

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

I tried to learn Object oriented programming in Python always get a TypeError.

Here is my complete code:

```
class Graph():
    def __init__(self):
        self.num_vertices = 0
        self.num_edges = 0
        self.vertices = {}
        

    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self.vertices.values())

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return f'Graph with {self.num_vertices} vertices and {self.num_edges} edges.'

    def add_vertices(self, vertex_names):
        for vertex_name in vertex_names:
            if vertex_name not in self.vertices.keys():
                self.vertices.update({vertex_name: Vertex(vertex_name)})
                self.num_vertices += 1
     
    def add_edge(self, vertex_name1, vertex_name2):
        if vertex_name1 != vertex_name2 and vertex_name1 not in self.vertices[vertex_name2].neighbors:
            if vertex_name1 or vertex_name2 not in self.vertices.keys():
                self.add_vertices([vertex_name1, vertex_name2])
        
            self.num_edges += 1
            self.vertices[vertex_name1].add_neighbor(self.vertices[vertex_name2])
            self.vertices[vertex_name2].add_neighbor(self.vertices[vertex_name1])

    def get_max_degree(self):
        degrees = []
        for vertex in self.vertices.values():
            degrees.append(len(vertex.neighbors))
        return max(degrees)
    

class Bipartite_Graph(Graph):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.partA = []
        self.partB = []

        super().__init__()
     
    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return f'Bipartite graph with {len(self.partA)} vertices in A, {len(self.partB)} vertices in B and {self.num_edges} edges.'


    def add_vertices(self, vertex_names, partition):
        for vertex in vertex_names:
            if partition == 'A':
                self.partA.append(vertex)
                super().add_vertices([vertex])
            else:
                self.partB.append(vertex)
                super().add_vertices([vertex])
        

    def add_edge(self, vertex_nameA, vertex_nameB):
        if vertex_nameA not in self.partB and vertex_nameB not in self.partA:
            super().add_edge(vertex_nameA, vertex_nameB)
```

When I use:

```
B = Bipartite_Graph()
B.add_vertices(['a1','a2'],'A')
B.add_vertices(['b1'],'B')
B.add_edge('a1','b1')
```

then I get the TypeError:

```
line 36, in add_edge
    self.add_vertices([vertex_name1, vertex_name2])
TypeError: Bipartite_Graph.add_vertices() missing 1 required positional argument: 'partition'
```

The problem is, that always the add_vertices of the subclass get called  not the add_vertices in the main class.

Comment: That's polymorphism. *self* is still a subclass instance (even if in superclass code). Changing method signatures in subclasses is a bad idea.

Comment: That is the expected behavior in Python. Overriding (overloading doesn't exist in Python, at least not in a natural way) a method with another that requires more or other parameters indicates a bad OOP design.

Comment: If you are familiar with C++, (and if I recall correctly) you can think of *all* methods as being virtual methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the Liskov Substitution Principle, you can't change the signature of a method in a child class in a way that makes it incompatible with the same method in a parent class. If `Graph.add_vertices` only takes names, that's all `BipartiteGraph.add_vertices` can take.

Generally speaking, all methods in Python behave like C++ virtual methods: the method called is determined by the runtime type of `self`, not the method in which `self` is used.

An invariant on an instance of `BipartiteGraph` is that no edge added will *violate* the existing partition. That means you don't need to classify a vertex as being in one half or the other until you actually add an edge that forces such a choice.

```
class BipartiteGraph(Graph):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.part_A = set()
        self.part_B = set()

    def add_edge(self, vA, vB):
        # Assuming these are directed edges; if undirected,
        # this check is a little more complicated.
        if vA in self.partB or vB in self.partA:
            raise ValueError(f"Edge ({vA}, {vB}) violates the partition")

        super().add_edge(vA, vB)

        self.part_A.add(vA)
        self.part_B.add(vB)
```

Answer (score 0):

The behavior you want isn't clear to me from the Question, but you can call a method of the class it inherited from with `super()`

For example

```py
class Foo(Bar):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()  # calls Bar's __init__()
        # now do more with Foo
```

While if you want to make a new instance of a class with the method call, you can use `@classmethod`

For example
(modified from https://stackoverflow.com/a/12179752/4541045)

```py
class Date:
    def __init__(self, day=0, month=0, year=0):
        self.day   = day
        self.month = month
        self.year  = year
    def __repr__(self):
        return f"{type(self).__name__}({self.year}-{self.month}-{self.day})"
    @classmethod
    def from_string(cls, date):
        year, month, day = map(int, date.split('-'))
        date = cls(day, month, year)
        return date
```

```py
>>> Date.from_string("2024-02-01")
Date(2024-2-1)
```