# Python beginner Class variable Error

Tags: python, class, python-3.x, class-variables

this is my first question, so sorry...
I'm a beginner with python and coding in general, and i wanted to create a class called 'Map' that would have the following class variables:

```
class Map:
    height = 11  
    width = 21

    top = [['#']*width]
    middle = [['#']+[' ']*(width-2)+['#'] for i in range(height-2)]
    field = top + middle + top

b = Map()

Shell:
>>> middle = [['#']+[' ']*(width-2)+['#'] for i in range(height-2)]
    NameError: name 'width' is not defined
```

If i put the variables outside of the class it works.
What am I doing wrong??

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Did you go through the [classes tutorial](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html)?

Comment: b.width? b.height? Since you are outside the class the Map. See this post it will help you understand better: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/68645/static-class-variables-in-python

Comment: I'm using IDLE not sure if that is important, also thanks again for taking your time to help me (:

Comment: @Padraic Cunningham if I put all of those variables under 'def __init__(self):' it works but, I want them to be Class variables, also if I change 'middle = [['#']+[' ']*(width-2)+['#']' to  'middle = [['#']+[' ']*(21-2)+['#']' it also works...why?

Comment: @Cookiesforhelp, I added an answer with some relevant documentation

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/executionmodel.html#naming):

> Names refer to objects. Names are introduced by name binding operations. Each occurrence of a name in the program text refers to the binding of that name established in the innermost function block containing the use.
>
> A block is a piece of Python program text that is executed as a unit. The following are blocks: a module, a function body, and a class definition. Each command typed interactively is a block. A script file (a file given as standard input to the interpreter or specified as a command line argument to the interpreter) is a code block. A script command (a command specified on the interpreter command line with the ‘-c‘ option) is a code block. The string argument passed to the built-in functions eval() and exec() is a code block.
>
> A code block is executed in an execution frame. A frame contains some administrative information (used for debugging) and determines where and how execution continues after the code block’s execution has completed.
>
> A scope defines the visibility of a name within a block. If a local variable is defined in a block, its scope includes that block. If the definition occurs in a function block, the scope extends to any blocks contained within the defining one, unless a contained block introduces a different binding for the name. **The scope of names defined in a class block is limited to the class block; it does not extend to the code blocks of methods – this includes comprehensions and generator expressions since they are implemented using a function scope**. This means that the following will fail:

```
class A:
    a = 42
    b = list(a + i for i in range(10))
```

list comps in python3 have their own scope, as opposed to python2 where your code would work as is.

If you take the following example using python2, you can see how variables leaking the scope of the list comp could cause some problems:

```
class A:
    a = 42
    b = [a for a in range(10)]

a = A()

print(a.a)
9
```

You have a few options, you could   use `__init__` creating instance attributes:

```
class Map:
    def __init__(self):
        self.height = 11
        self.width = 21
        self.top = [['#']*self.width]
        self.middle = [['#']+[' ']*(self.width-2)+['#'] for i in range(self.height-2)]
        self.field = self.top + self.middle + self.top
m=Map()
print(m.field)
```

Using a method:

```
class Map:
    @staticmethod
    def meth():
        height = 11
        width = 21
        top = [['#']*width]
        middle = [['#']+[' ']*(width-2)+['#'] for i in range(height-2)]
        field = top + middle + top
        return field

b = Map()


print(b.meth())
```

What you choose is really dependant on what you want to do.

Comment: So... the "for" loop function inside the list does not have access to the width variable?

Comment: @Cookiesforhelp, yes, exactly.

Comment: Thank you for your time and the links but, one last question in the python2 example does the variable lose "byte data" to became another number because that is weird

Comment: @Cookiesforhelp. the name is rebound to the last value in the loop.

Comment: ohhh ok so even in python2 it completely ignores "a = 42" and just creates a new/or overwrites "a".

Comment: it is no different than have a variable `a = 42` then on the next line having `a = 9`, you are rebinding the name `a` to 9

Comment: one more question why is it that the "for" loop inside the list does not have access to the width variable but it does have access to the height variable, inside the list ? again thank you for your time.

Comment: @Cookiesforhelp, because the names in the for loop access the variables in the outside scope, if you move height to where width is you will see the same outcome.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use b.width and b.height to refer the member variables define. 
Refer this post for some explanation about accessing member variables - [Accessing a class' member variables in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3434581/accessing-a-classs-variable-in-python)

Comment: This is wrong and not actually related to the issue at all, the error happens ever before the instance is created

Answer (score 0):

I am also a beginner in Python as well

use the **init**() function to define variables

```
class Map:
    def __init__(self,height,width,top,middle,field):
        self.height = height
        self.width = width
        self.top = top
        self.middle = middle
        self.field = field
```

Also, watch some OOP Python beginner tutorials on YouTube. They really help