# python "'y' object has no attribute 'x'" when calling a grandparent method x

Tags: python, class, inheritance, pygame

Im attempting to call the grandparent method getColor() from the Class below.

This is the grandparent class in its own file:

```
class IsVisible(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    white = (255,255,255)
    black = (0,0,0)
    red = (255,0,0)
    blue = (0,0,255)
    green = (0,255,0)

def getColor(self):
        return self.color
```

This is the parent class and child class.

```
from IsVisible import *
class Object(IsVisible):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Object, self).__init__() 
        self.posSize = []
    def getPosSize(self):
        return self.posSize

class Rectangle(Object):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Rectangle, self).__init__()
        self.color = self.blue
        self.posSize = [20,50,100,100]
```

So Im trying to call `getColor` by creating an object

```
rectangle = Rectangle()
```

and then calling

```
rectangle.getColor()
```

However I'm getting an error. Namely:

```
AttributeError: 'Rectangle' object has no attribute 'getColor'
```

Now I have no idea how to solve this. I have tried to google "python call grandparent method" but I only get instructions for how to call a method that is overrun... I believe I have stated the inheritance correctly so I don't know what the problem is. Could anyone help me?

Comment: In the code you showed, `getColor` is not indented under `IsVisible`.  Is it in your real code?  It should be.  **Also** Please change `Object` to another name --- too much risk of confusion with the builtin `object`.  **And,** what Python version?

Comment: PS welcome to the site!  Thanks for including detail in this question --- many forget to do so.  Check out the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) for more about asking questions that will attract quality answers.  You also get a badge for reading the whole tour. :)

Answer (score 1):

If it's just indentation (and nothing else is jumping out at me) —

```
class IsVisible(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    white = (255,255,255)
    black = (0,0,0)
    red = (255,0,0)
    blue = (0,0,255)
    green = (0,255,0)

    def getColor(self):    # <--- indent this
        return self.color
```

But be careful about class vs. instance variables.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3434596/2877364) for more (not copied here since it's not the answer to your question above).

Also, please don't use `Object` as the name of a class :) .  It is too likely to lead to confusion with the real `object`, or to confuse the reader about what you mean.  How about `ColoredShape` instead of `IsVisible`, `PositionedShape` instead of `Object`, and `Rectangle(PositionedShape)`?

Comment: Oh, I see! Thank you very much for spotting it! And thanks for the suggestion of name change. I was uncertain what to name it before.

Comment: @Slibbfalusken Good news --- happy to help!  If this answer solved your problem, would you please hit the checkmark to accept this answer?  That will clear your question off the "unanswered" lists --- and we will both get reputation points :) .  ([tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour))