# Create one pexpect session only for all objects in python

Tags: python, oop, pexpect

I'm trying to create a class to connect to box using pexpect and grab some data from that box, and I have difficulty of creating a function that contains the pexpect session for my box and initializes it for each object that I create in the class code example below.

```
class A:
   def __init__(self)
       # in this way a session will be created for each object and i don't 
       # need that i need only one session to open for any object created.
       session = pexpect.spawn('ssh myhost')
       session.expect('myname@myhost#')

   def get_some_data(self,command)
       session.sendline(command)
       session.expect('myname@myhost#')
       list = session.before.splitlines()
       return list
```

now my problem is if I do create a new object a new session will be created for each object, and that is not required I can use only one session for every object I create from this class

Comment: So I assume code is working, you just need to workout a single session strategy?

Comment: yes, it's working but i needed the ability to open one pexpect connection for all objects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a [class method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html?highlight=classmethod#classmethod) to connect and set a [class variable](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#class-and-instance-variables) for the `pexpect`'s instance (child). Then instance methods in this class can use that class variable

```
import pexpect

class Comms:
    Is_connected = False
    Name = None
    ssh = None

    @classmethod
    def connect(cls, name):
        cls.Name = name
        cls.ssh = pexpect.spawn('ssh ' + name)
        cls.ssh.expect('password:')
        cls.ssh.sendline('*****')
        cls.ssh.expect('> ')
        print cls.ssh.before, cls.ssh.after
        cls.Is_connected = True

    @classmethod
    def close(cls):
        cls.ssh.close()
        cls.ssh, cls.Is_connected = None, False

    def check_conn(self):
        print self.Name + ' is ' + str(self.Is_connected)
        return self.Is_connected

    def cmd(self, command):
        self.ssh.sendline(command)
        self.ssh.expect('> ')
        return self.ssh.before + self.ssh.after
```

The `self.ssh` used in instance methods is a way to use a class variable inside the class, *if it is not assigned to*. If it were assigned to that would instead create an instance variable with the same name. In this case that should not happen since there is no reason to assign to `ssh` in this class.

A class method receives the class as an implicit argument so `cls.ssh` can be used. Inside an instance method one can also get a reference to the class and then use `cls.ssh`

```
def cmd(self, command):
    cls = self.__class__
    cls.ssh.sendline(command)
    ...
```

A class variable can be used anywhere as `Comms.ssh`.  This is a rather bare-bones class.

Now connect to a host using the class method and run commands via different instances

```
from comms import Comms

userathost = 'xxx@xxxxx'

print 'Connect to ' + userathost
Comms.connect(userathost)

conn_1 = Comms()
conn_1.check_conn()
print conn_1.cmd('whoami')
print

conn_2 = Comms()
print 'With another instance object: pwd:'
print conn_2.cmd('pwd')

Comms.close()
```

With a real `userathost`, and redacted for personal details in `[description]`,  this prints

```
Connect to xxx@xxxxx

Last login: Sat Aug 12 01:04:52 2017 from *****
[... typical greeting on this host]
[my prompt] > 
xxx@xxxxx is True
whoami
[my username]
[my prompt] > 

With another instance object: pwd:
pwd
[path to my home]
[my prompt] >
```

The connection should be set up and output handled more nicely, but that's about `pexpect`.

---

For class/static methods and variables see, for instance

- [Static class variables in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68645/4653379)
- [In Python how can I access “static” class variables within class methods](https://stackoverflow.com/q/707380/4653379)
- [Variables inside and outside of a class __init__() function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1537202/4653379)
- [What are “class methods” and “instance methods”, in Python?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/306092)
- [Accessing a class' member variables in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3434581/4653379)