# Can't find a class variable in python

Tags: python, attributeerror

So am currently writing a simple settings page for a project... and so this is what the page looks like:

```
class Settings(object):
   def _init_(self):
       self.screen_width = 1200
       self.screen_height = 800
       self.bg_color = (230,230,230)

st = Settings()
print(st.screen_width)
```

and so I followed the instruction on what this other question:
[Accessing a class' member variables in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3434581/accessing-a-class-member-variables-in-python#new-answer?newreg=3b2f51bfcd3b441187a584696245f2d8) but I still have issues accessing a single variable...

this is the error I get: [image: error_code]

it basically says that the current class (which is "Settings") doesn't have an attribute called "screen_width"

am starting to think its my text editor... I use VSCode but I don't know maybe am missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have made a minor mistake..in your init function it should be `__init__` not `_init_`

```
class Settings(object):
   def __init__(self):
      self.screen_width = 1200
      self.screen_height = 800
      self.bg_color = (230,230,230)

st = Settings()
print(st.screen_width)
```

Answer (score 0):

Mis-spelled [`__init__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__init__), `_init_` should be replaced with `__init__`:

```py
class Settings(object):
   def __init__(self):  # <---
       self.screen_width = 1200
       self.screen_height = 800
       self.bg_color = (230,230,230)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you have make mistake in **int** function
Instant of this

```
def _init_(self):
```

Change to
def **int**(self)