# Importing list from another class in Python 3

Tags: python-3.x

I tried to import a list from another class in Python 3, but I always get an empty list.
I researched the problem and found similar questions here on stackoverflow and elsewhere, however they didn't work. Because in my class i had an **init** method. And that interfered with their answers.

I'm posting a dummy code here to give you an idea of my code:-

main.py:-

```
number_of_cars = 3
factory = "XYZ"


class Home:
    big_list = []

    def __init__(self, _cars, _factory):
        self.cars = _cars
        self.factory = _factory

    def add_to_list(self):
        for x in range(0, 3):
            self.big_list.append(x)
        print(self.big_list)


def main():
    home = Home(number_of_cars, factory)
    home.add_to_list()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

extra.py:-

```
from main import Home


class Extra:

    def print_func(self):
        number_of_cars = 3
        factory = "XYZ"
        x = Home(number_of_cars, factory).big_list
        print(x)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    extra = Extra()
    extra.print_func()
```

What I tried:-
-I tried using the getattr(home, 'all_addresses'), it didn't work
-I tried to write Home().all_addresses, but that resulted in an error of I have to enter number_of_cars and factory, again, which will result in an error while I run my actual code

I know I didn't post my actual code, I'm sorry for that, but that's for security reasons.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: It is quite hard to understand what you are doing.
all_addresses is an empty list, what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: What does not work for you? The way you access - home.all_addresses - should work. What is error message? Or how do you know it does not work?

Comment: @Pitto you're quite right. I edited my code

Comment: @lllrnr101 I don't get an error message, I get an empty list

Comment: Still I cannot read a part of the code calling add_to_list
Did you test your code before sharing it?

Comment: That is because all_addresses is Class variable and self.all_addresses is instance variable.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Accessing a class' member variables in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3434581/accessing-a-class-member-variables-in-python)

Comment: What I mean is that if you don't call add_to_list somewhere (e.g. in your init) it will never be called and therefore you will just have an empty list in all_addresses.

Comment: @Pitto I have completely re-written my code now.. if you run main.py alone, it will give you a result as expected.. However, if you run extra.py, it won't...

run the code and give it a try

Answer (score 0):

In your main.py you need to put a way to get what you need in an accessible way, like make that main function return that Home initialize or make/extract those part you need into its own function

for example

main.py

```
...

def initialize_data():
    return Home(number_of_cars, factory)

def main():
    main = initialize_data()
...
```

extra.py

```
import main 

class Extra:

    def count(self):
        home = main.initialize_data()
        for i in enumerate(home.all_addresses):
            print("hey")
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to run the population method in init, for example:

```
number_of_cars = 3
factory = "XYZ"

class Home:

    all_addresses = []

    def __init__(self, _cars, _factory):
        self.add_to_list()
        self.n_cars = _cars
        self.factory = _factory

    def add_to_list(self):
        for x in range(0, 3):
            self.all_addresses.append(x)

def main():
    main = Home(number_of_cars, factory)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: i did this and ran extra.py, it printed the list 2 times

Comment: What do you want to obtain, at this point I am unsure...
I think you want to remove the main method from the first class and just initialize it from the second.

Comment: Hi there,

if you found my code useful please don't forget upvoting it and/or choosing it as final answer.